# Can I get a mod to undelete a question I just deleted?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, undelete

Sorry.  I just posted a question and 5 minutes later when I thought I had found that the problem was caused by an XCode bug, I deleted it.  I was wrong.  The problem still exists, and I'd rather not ask the question again if it can be restored.

The question was in regard to iOS/XCode/Interface-Builder and the default styling of a UIToolbar.

If this can't be done, I understand.  Let me know and I'll ask it again. :(

**UPDATE:**
For those who have responded, thank you.  [The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794309/why-are-two-different-uitoolbars-defaulting-to-different-styles) has been restored.

Comment: Do you still have the link to the question? If you do, you can do it yourself. Otherwise, it takes a ♦ moderator.

Comment: (As an aside: it's [also possible to answer one's own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it).)

Comment: (As another aside: one can use `@replies` to address an editor of a post; see [the Markdown help](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-reply). That way you could address @mmyers, who silently fixed your problem and then tagged this very question as `status-completed`. It *might* also work on [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9794309/revisions), but I don't know if undeleting qualifies for `@replies` too.)

Comment: (@Gilles, see also Uphill's answer. Cheers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators can see your deleted questions in [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469319/rlh?tab=questions).
If you could report the question title, or part of it, that would make easier to find the question you are referring to, but hopefully you don't have many deleted questions.

If you have the link to the question, 10k users could vote to undelete your question; with enough votes, your question would be undeleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 10k reputation, then use your browser's history feature to find your deleted question back.  Then just undelete it.

If you don't have 10k, then you'll [see a specific 404](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71179/add-message-saying-question-was-deleted-instead-of-the-generic-page-not-found/85858#85858) as soon as the page is reloaded. You then still need help from a moderator.

Comment: Since he has fewer than 10K rep points on SO, this will only work if it's still cached. Once the deleted question's page is reloaded, it'd give him a 404.

Comment: Does the 404 page actually return an HTTP response of 404?  If so, I think that's why going back in my browser (Chrome) would show the 404 page.  This could, possibly, be changed for the sake of the original post

Comment: Yes, @RLH, [it does return HTTP 404 Not Found](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125176/deleted-questions-should-return-410-gone-instead-of-404-not-found), at least: [when not having 10k](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F126270%2Fin-comments-let-esc-discard-changes-and-close-the-textarea&http=1.1&type=GET&uak=0).

Comment: That said, @RLH, I'm not sure what you want to change? Given the "[that's you!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71179/add-message-saying-question-was-deleted-instead-of-the-generic-page-not-found/85858#85858)" I'm quite sure the team has decided that even for one's own posts the 404 is to be preferred over [the reddish page](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7rRYm.png) that 10k's get to see. See also Jeff's answer and comments in [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me/53297#53297).