# Do CW questions count towards the Self-Learner badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, community-wiki, self-answer

I've searched Meta and found no answer, and based on the description of the badge, I see no reason why they wouldn't, but since Community Wiki posts are a bit different from regular posts, I think it might be useful to make it clear whether or not they count.

**Should** Community Wiki questions/answers count?

Comment: Gimme two upvotes here if you want to find out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110565/del-partial-delta-nabla-correct-enunciation/115253#115253 :)

Comment: I recently got Self Learner for [this CW answer](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/3442/31260) at Programmers Meta and for [this CW answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123386/how-to-deal-with-link-rot-caused-by-deletion-of-popular-off-topic-questions/125172#125172) at MSO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do.

I [got it](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/14/self-learner?userid=24293) for [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/115253/24293) on Math.SE.

I've added this to the [complete description of badges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/68258/52)

Yes, it would be nice if non-CW and CW were explicitly specified on the badges page since tagmadges don't work the same way.

Answer (score 2):

They should. I say should because I've never personally seen one awarded for a community wiki post.

The [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) FAQ states:

> The original author still gets badges based on community posts.

I assume this applies to *all* the regular badges. I know it applies to badges like Nice Answer and similar which I have gotten on community wiki posts previously. I also know for sure that you do *not* get tag badges for community wiki posts.

Comment: +1. That quote suggests the badge should be awarded in this situation. However, the tag badges specifically state that CW posts do not count. I think it would be a bit clearer if Self-Learner specifically stated whether or not they count.