# Can we undelete my question that was cited by reputable sources?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, moderation

I've gone to visit Stack Overflow today and have noticed that I lost some reputation. One of my questions had been deleted. This is normal to me now. When I saw which question, I was surprised as it was [How deep are your Unit-Tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153234/how-deep-are-your-unit-tests/)

It was one of mine but one that had got a fabulous response from key individuals in the field.
(For those how can't see the question it was regarding Unit testing - answered by [Kent Beck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13842/kent-beck) <sup>**[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Beck)**</sup>). The question had nearly

- 10k views
- 80+ upvotes
- 233 upvoted answer by the inventor of the practice
- many other contributions
- [linked](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3159-testing-like-the-tsa) to by leading industry figures <sup>**[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/37signals)**</sup>

Now I'm not sure how much of this is down to my ego being bruised and how much of this is me being objective but I feel it is a great a shame that this question has been deleted. I think that by deleting this question that Stack Overflow has extinguished an interesting question. What I can see is that the question does not have a canonical answer and so does not fit into the current guidelines but surely it has a place on somewhere else in SE, such as Programmers. There is no reason given on the question either. Is there a way to deal with issues like these?

Comment: @JohnNolan I think I made your title a little less "yelly" roll back if you feel it is necessary.

Comment: There are 2 issues, I guess. The fact that there are deletions with out reason, and where is the best place to raise an issue with a mod decision. (I've phrased that as 'complain?'). You seem to have read my acknowledgement of the work that mods do as a complaint against them. It wasn't.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Already noticed, and deleted my (now obsolete) comments, thanks for editing. John, now this is a question I can upvote.

Comment: @YannisRizos - what if I rollback? :)

Comment: JohnNolan - then @YannisRizos will be able to remove the upvote or even down-vote if he sees fit.

Comment: YEAH STICK TO THE MAN JOHN

Comment: That definitely meets the criteria for a historical lock.  Done and done.

Comment: the man is stuck too - thanks @BilltheLizard

Comment: @BilltheLizard Good work sir.

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [how to deal with link rot caused by deletion of popular off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123386/165773)

Comment: @BilltheLizard even more related: [Why were historically significant questions deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114908/155556)

Comment: @gnat see my comment above ^

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA agreed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to close of this question:

@BillTheLizard has marked the question in question as **historically significant** and reopened it.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)