# Why only -1 in reputation when down vote someone?

Tags: discussion

Why we get only -1 when we down vote someone? Why just -1 and not -2 or -5?

When you down voting someone there is basically two reasons:

**Main Reason**

You dislike someone's Question or Answer.

**Secondary Reasons**

1. The Question or Answer doesn't fulfil the site's  quality requirements.
2. The person who down votes answers has also posted an answer to the same question, so s/he tries to show that his/her answer is better than the others.

I also want to ask if it's possible that the person get the down vote normally but when any community persons verify that his/her down voting is correct than he will get his/her reputation back? Or an automatic system, if a person down vote and after or before when this question or answer get 2 up votes than his/her reputation down and if the question or answer gets the more down vote this answer or question is really not met the requirements

Comment: Where exactly you got all those utterly wrong ideas? What makes you think this way? You're member for only four days and got no downvotes as far as I could see.

Comment: Then we should get +1 or +2 when (down)voting as a reward for investing time and trying to make stackoverflow better. No, serious... -1 is good (almost to much) since the author will get -2 (+10 for one upvote)

Comment: I read this question three times and I still don't understand what it's asking.

Answer (score 7):

> You dislike someone's Question or Answer.

Your first wrong assumption. Votes are a *tool* to regulate the content of the site, not the users. The voting system separates *good* from *bad* stuff. You should vote based on the tooltips of the vote-buttons, which go like this:

```
This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear.
This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

This answer is useful.
This answer is not useful.
```

> The Question or Answer doesn't fulfil the site's quality requirements.

Your second wrong assumption: That's the ***only and primary reason***.

> The person who down votes answers has also posted an answer to the same question, so s/he tries to show that his/her answer is better than the others.

Uhhhh...that's so wrong in so many ways...

Comment: 'The Question or Answer doesn't fulfil the site's quality requirements - That's the only and primary reason.'... I rarely downvote for quality reasons.  I'll usually either edit to improve if possible, or flag / close vote if not.  I'd tend to downvote because it's wrong...

Comment: @forsvarir: True, but there are cases in which neither flagging nor editing is reasonable. F.e. a link-only-answer. It does not qualify for flags, but is not useful either if you don't feel like editing it into a full fledged answer.

Comment: hmm per my experience **link-only-answers** [qualify for flags fairly well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116311/165773)

Comment: @gnat: Uh, that's new to me, but may it be.

Comment: You get upvotes for *"Uhhhh...that's so wrong in so many ways..."*? Man, my Meta trolling just got so much easier! ;-)