# Disputed link-only flag. Why?

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers, disputed-flags

Today I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837682/what-is-the-main-advantage-of-laravel-over-codeigniter/20837966#20837966) as "low-quality", since it mainly consist in a link to a blog post and a pretty neutral opinion.

The link itself is not really useful too - though interesting, it doesn't deal with the question topic (which is, by the way, pretty opinion-based, and attracted a lot of link-only answers), but nonetheless I decided to avoid the "Not an answer" flag and go for the closest to what I feel.

The flag now is marked as `disputed` (I know what that means), but is it really? Moreover, two high-rep users already commented on it (with somewhat contrasting opinions, but both think the answer isn't enough), so that should enforce my flag, or at least give it some acknowledgment.

I know, "Just walk way and go on", but I'd like to have a better understanding of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flag declined, link-only answer subsequently deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140062/flag-declined-link-only-answer-subsequently-deleted) and of [Can we get some consensus on what flag to use for link only answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I read a couple questions on meta before, regarding flags, and I thought it was better to avoid burdening moderators with custom flags when other options would have been viable

Comment: whole question is low quality and most of the answers are garbage, too: "This post has some advantage of using Laravel over Codeigniter also: <link>" / "Try read this post i hope this will help when deciding. <link>" - answers my ass. [Why](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202667/165773) is that almost every time I see SO question I loose precious rep on downvoting crap like that

Comment: @gnat thanks for the links, especially the second one

Answer (score 5):

If you flag an answer as "very low quality", then it goes to the Low Quality Posts queue. [4 users voted to delete the answer, but then someone choosed "Looks Good"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3696820), so the answer wasn't deleted.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know one user was enough to reverse the vote of other 4

Comment: @DamienPirsy The low quality queue gives users with less rep a power that is usually reserved for 20ks -- the ability to vote to delete answers. There better be unanimity in the voting.

Comment: @DamienPirsy: The count of "Looks Good" needed is equal to the number of VLQ flags. So, in this case, one VLQ flag, so one "Looks Good" vote is needed to 'reverse' the other votes.