# 2014 SO Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, election

In connection with the Stack Overflow moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221594/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- During the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, February 17th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 3:00 pm EST on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this new process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Is this in lieu of the town hall events of previous elections?

Comment: @Pekka Yep, though that's not to stop people from organizing a chat session.

Comment: "Did somebody ask you to run?"

Comment: *Chris Hansen walks in...* - 'Why don't you have a seat over there?'

Comment: Do I have a better chance to win if I smoke crack?

Comment: Why yes, @RobFord! Your willingness to stand against narcotics oppression is a sure strength in this candidacy.

Comment: Judging from the top 20 answers this looks like a pretty bad idea.  The candidates' own proposals would be more interesting (as opposed to their reaction to other people's proposals.)

Comment: @Andomar I'm not sure what you mean by "The candidates' own proposals". As in, questions submitted by the candidates to each other?

Comment: @GraceNote: I mean, what is the candidate inwardly enthousiastic about, as opposed to foreign ideas that he is forced to respond to.

Comment: @Andomar One *could* ask a question about what the candidate is inwardly enthusiastic about. Quite a few of the runs of this Q&A on others sites on the network feature questions like "What is the one big thing you wish you could change?" or "What do you feel is the most pressing topic?".

Comment: Can we not do this again?  Next time, let's just create an "ask-the-candidates" tag and let folks post genuine questions, instead of abusing the platform like this.  The candidates could actually post genuine answers then.

Comment: I like this format - it's much more organic in its asynchronous nature than the town hall meetings. But the idea of, say, a `ask-the-candidates-2014` tag sounds interesting as well (although it would likely cause *much* more unrest than this one question, @Robert? You'd have to put down every bad question individually)

Comment: @Pëkka: Well, all this does is give them a list of questions to ask in the Town Hall Chat.  It doesn't give the candidates the opportunity to respond asynchronously.

Comment: brb, flagging every answer as not an answer.

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood. Yeah, then I'm in favour of having a tag (maybe a mod-only tag that only questions with +5 votes can get?)

Comment: @Robert The candidates answer on the thread I post this week. Granted, only a small selection of the questions as provided (though we may or may not increase the number just because of the number of good entries).

Comment: So if you're using Meta to host the election for SO, I guess that means the MSO/MSE split is postponed till after the election?

Comment: @TRiG That would be correct. It's also postponed until we get a few other things fixed up.

Comment: @GraceNote, how can I contact you about an issue regarding reputation on one of the exchanges?

Comment: @John Use the Contact Us form located at the bottom of every page, and explain the situation as thoroughly as you can. If you specifically need to reach me, you can mention my name in the explanation and it'll find its way to me.

Comment: @GraceNote, will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 308):

An asker repeatedly flags their own question and says that they need to delete it or they'll be fired, because they mistakenly posted proprietary code. There are several good answers on that question. What do you do?

Comment: That's an interesting one. Presumably this comes from real experience?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Getting close to once a day, particularly if you expand this to include students and assignments.

Comment: Good _grief_...

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Thus: https://twitter.com/bradlarson/status/410442895842217984

Comment: Should we get the StackTwitterBot to retweet that?

Comment: @BradLarson Is this a question that a mod even has the right to answer?  Aren't they *obligated* to honor such a request?  If SE doesn't have the legal right to this content, are they allowed to continue hosting it just because someone else mistakenly claimed that SE was allowed to publish it?  Or are you limiting such requests to only formal DCMA requests?

Comment: @Servy - We handle these flags all the time, as I indicated above. There can be complexities here, which is why I see it as a useful question for moderator candidates to answer.

Comment: @Servy: No.  A user can request that their answer be disassociated from their account, but users license the content to the community when they post it.  See http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/.  There's no requirement or obligation that we delete an OP's post simply because they request it.

Comment: It does raise an interesting question when the OP did not have any legal basis for licensing the content to SO in the first place.

Comment: @Lightness methinks that's what the DMCA takedown process is there for

Comment: @Pëkka: I suppose that makes sense

Comment: They might edit the post, can't they?

Comment: @DavidKernin Sure, but the edit history is visible. If they're actually in deep trouble, just editing won't save them.

Comment: Right, I didn't consider it..

Comment: This gets even more intresting with stuff like stackprinter. The internet never forgets.

Comment: When looking at the from a moral perspective, isn't the answer always 'yes'?

Comment: Couldn't we have a function for anonymizing the code and removing it from the history, so that we do not lose valuable answers?

Comment: It would be beneficial if the community had a way to clean up a question (the mod can remove identifying text from the post in an edit) and then modify the POST history with the edit. In that way its as if the information wasnt there. I mean how hard is it to use placeholders for company names (in the comments), or other variable names.

Comment: Interesting question, though maybe a bit philosophical in nature. Alas, maybe the real question is, if the poster was dumb enough to post proprietary code, is he/she smart enough to have a question worth asking?

Comment: I'm just dumbfounded. Supposedly good user experience is all about allowing people to make mistakes and then to fix them without penalty. There **is absolutely no argument here**. Anything short of letting the users wipe the code they had no right to post is like spitting in their faces and saying "Haha, no, you entered zero, we'll crash and your satellite will deorbit. The flotsam is scheduled for pickup somewhere mid-Pacific in 48 hours. Over and out". The good answers are irrelevant. They can be retained, the asker or moderators are free to paraphrase the code later. What's so hard here?

Comment: @rmayer06 Philosphical in nature? Seriously? Nothing philosophical here. It's user experience 101. That it's not solved in the favor of the user is just as bad as the fact that you can't wipe wrongly uploaded pictures, since the imgur account is owned by SO and only they can ultimately wipe the pics.\

Comment: @Shawn The proprietary part of the code might be crucial to the question and not anonymizable; for example, an algorithm or data structure. Plus, the employer might simply be obstinate about the issue: "remove the post entirely or that's it!"

Comment: @KubaOber: A policy that states that anyone can delete anything they post at any time is ripe for abuse, which is why there are mechanisms in the software that prevent such deletion, and why contributors are required to license their contributions to the community without conditions.  If someone doesn't want their code on the Internet, the way they prevent that is by not posting it in the first place.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, good user experience sometimes can be ripe for abuse. Surely there are ways of flagging excessive removals for review, with appropriate consequences. I find absolutely no persuasion in arguments that user mistakes must be irreversible. Saying "contributors are required to license their contributions to the community" is irrelevant. They made a mistake and they didn't have the right to issue such a license, etc. Telling people to use DMCA for such cases is textbook bad user experience. It's like those websites where you can only call to cancel, but you can sign up online.

Comment: @KubaOber: What about the user experience of other community participants who freely give of their precious free time to answer questions in good faith, only to have their content suddenly disappear without warning?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I basically find the entire anti-deletion argument to be putting one's head in the sand and screaming "but you licensed!".   Demonstrably, they didn't, they couldn't, they were unaware, whatever. It's their right to make such a mistake, and for it to be easily fixable. This is in the same boat as the un-removable images - the equivalent of "account cancellation by phone call only". It is unconscionable that a mistake that is *simple to make* (upload wrong code, wrong image) has to take in improportionately amount of effort to undo.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry, nobody forced those other participants to give those answers. I don't believe it is or will be a problem that causes inordinate waste of time to the answerers. Again - if it becomes problematic, people who abuse it can be penalized. There are mechanisms for that in place.

Comment: Everyone: these are proposed questions for the moderator candidates. If these are used, it will be up to the candidates themselves to answer them. I don't think the comments under each question are the right place to have an argument about how all of us would answer these questions. I think we've established that there is no clear-cut answer to this, so can we take this argument somewhere else?

Comment: @KubaOber: Brad has a point.  If you need to discuss this further, open a new question on Meta.

Comment: Same as NDA issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94488/244217

Answer (score 205):

How would you handle situations involving less than warm welcomes given to new users?

For example, a new user posts a well written first question consisting of clearly defined requirements, admission of a high level of domain ignorance, and a request for the proper solution methodology, but no actual code attempts to tackle the problem.

Said question receives many downvotes and impolite comments. The asker gets upset about the situation and complains **to you directly** on chat and/or meta.

What would you do?

Comment: This happens often, and users will immediately leave the website if they're not treated with humility.

Comment: THIS f***king this is so important.

Comment: How do you show a level of effort in attempt to answer the question prior to asking it on SO? Because the well written question might be not OP's effort (interview questions and homework comes to mind).

Comment: I have never seen a question treated that way if it asked for **methodology** and not code.

Comment: I don't think moderators are very well suited to address this issue,  apart from removing really abrasive comments. They won't be able to hold hands individually due to sheer volume

Comment: and what about the repeated questions for asking the reasons for down votes?

Comment: @DavidKernin Sometimes it's not about quantity, but quality. Do we care about users who don't follow the rules? If we are willing to give them the benefit of the doubt, then perhaps it should be a simple rule that the first question someone asks can't be closed nor downvoted for a week. This should let everyone work it out.

Comment: I'm not sure about that but I'm sure that when you post a question and, for one reason or another, it gets downvoted without even a comment.. well that just feels bad if you wrote that in good faith. It should almost be mandatory to write a comment if you downvoted.

Comment: @Pëkka That's why I included "complains to you" in the question. It's unreasonable to expect moderators to give a tour the site to new users, but if an upset user seeks out and addresses a moderator directly, then the mod must offer some sort of response. Even total silence will be interpreted as commentary by the user (and none too positively in that case). I've added some explicit emphasis to that phrase.

Comment: @DVK Perhaps we have different definitions of methodology, because I see this with some regularity. My goal for the hypothetical is to describe a clear, well defined question which has no code, *might* be answerable without any, *might* be off topic, and is *not* "give the codez". A gray area question. The ambiguity is intentional, so we can get a glimpse of where a candidate's mind goes first - insight in to their temperament and moderation instincts. If you think the wording could be made clearer (I think so, but I'm not sure how to improve while keeping it succinct), please do edit.

Comment: I really feel bad about the new users who just signs up and posts his problem. Though ver less read the FAQ. And I think in this case we the users should be responsible to treat new users politely and nicely  and tell them to add more info in their question. Before downvoting any question we should check the history of the user whether s/he is new or not.

Comment: @Esoteric fair enough

Comment: This one is right on the spot question. for newbie like me, asking question while there is always some bad person going to down vote my question. I think, stackoverflow is a place for some of arrogant down voter.

Comment: This is not only for questions, it is also true for answers, and it is bad. Sometime i feel like those professionals dont have any humanity :(

Answer (score 129):

#### How many Close Vote reviews have you done?

- As a reviewer, how do you feel about size of [The Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) reaching over 110k?
- The community considers this a problem, as indicated eg by over 100 upvotes cast at [Close Votes review: I'm going on a strike!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208220/close-votes-review-im-going-on-a-strike) - what's your take on these concerns?
- What do you think of [New queue for moderators: questions that appear stuck in close votes review at SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198549/new-queue-for-moderators-questions-that-appear-stuck-in-close-votes-review-at-s)?

> [image: screen shot: 116.4k (hat tip to Pëkka)]

---

<sub>Update: **over 100 upvotes**, not bad for a question [accused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220314/2014-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/220319#comment714299_220319) of being "not relevant to a mod's duties". Thanks to all who share concerns expressed here!</sub>

Comment: Keep in mind that moderators are going to have very little influence on changes made to the CV queue.  That's a matter for the Community Managers, developers, and other SE employees.

Comment: @Servy I am rather interested to see their thought process, and their ideas about scale of question closures / reviews

Comment: -1, this is not a subject I think we should use to judge our moderator candidates by. I'm much more interested in learning their moderation style and what kind of actions they will be taking, instead of just learning their opinions on various topics that are popular with the meta culture.

Comment: @Rachel this, as you call it, "subject", is a matter of over 100K questions worthy either closure or being left open

Comment: This question reminds me of the people who ask things like "Whats your opinion on God" in politics and basing their vote on something like that. It's a popular topic, but has no bearing on how the person will act once in office or what steps they can/will take. The Close Queue is not a topic that moderators are expected to address in order to do their job. That's for the community and dev team. Sure mods can help out if they want to and/or have time to (don't forget, they have the flag queue to deal with), but it's not something I would expect mods to do,.

Comment: The CVQ issue has the potential to reveal the topics @Rachel mentions, if asked correctly; e.g., "the community considers this a problem, how would you respond to its concerns?" If a candidate's answer is, "I won't have any review limits and I cast binding votes, so I'll review 500 questions a day until the queue is empty", that's very indicative of moderation style and something I'd want to know about before casting votes. Agreed that a simple "is it a problem" is not probing enough; it needs an "and why or why not" at a minimum (though most of us probably take that as implicitly included).

Comment: @EsotericScreenName thanks! question wording was updated in line with your suggestion

Comment: This question is not relevant to a mod's duties.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think it's relevant to community _citizens_

Comment: Personally I think a perfectly valid answer to your edited question is *"Give them the appropriate links to the relevant questions, and encourage them to raise any new ideas and/or concerns that aren't already addressed on meta"*. It's the same generic answer I would expect from a wide range of subjects. Once again, this is not relevant to a moderators duties, and they have no more say than the rest of the community about how the CVQ gets handled. Also, 100 votes doesn't mean a real lot on Meta :)

Comment: _Or_ instead of any of that we could just close our eyes ["and pretend the problem doesn't exist"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195352/daily-close-votes-queue-limit#comment615699_195355)

Comment: @gnat How is recognizing that a given user's opinion on this issue isn't relevant to whether or not they are qualified to moderate the site an indication that the entire problem should be ignored?  The statement is simply that this is something to discuss through meta discussions, not through moderator screening, quite simply because moderators are no different from regular users when it comes to decisions on how to manage this problem.

Comment: @gnat Have you considered nominating yourself? You would have my vote.

Comment: @RobertHarvey hope newly elected moderators will be those who believe that reviewing and making decisions on closing / leaving open are relevant. Indifference may be one of the reasons why this very problem exists for so long

Comment: @gnat: Moderators are responsible for maintaining the mod queue.  **You** (and the other members of the community with close vote privileges) are responsible for maintaining the close queue.

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202854/165773

Comment: @gnat: That's a nice tool.  You should use it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's a nice _user_ of the tool I probably was the first to advertize. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151994/165773 (it only feels a bit sad that [after more than a half year on strike](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208220/close-votes-review-im-going-on-a-strike#comment663869_208220), I'm still in top 20 SO CV reviewers => means it's not advertized wide enough)

Comment: @gnat: Yeah, I knew what you meant.  Bill's first allegiance (and mine) is to the mod queue.  It's currently got 990 flags in it.  You won't see me in the Close Votes queue any time soon.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is a question; it's already public information, linked to from each candidate's nomination.

Comment: @Shog9 "how do you feel about size of The Queue reaching over 110k?" - this isn't linked (I think). Nor I am aware of where one can find how many CV reviews are done by a candidate

Comment: Click the "review history" link below their nomination, look for close/leave open reviews, @gnat. If you don't care about the *raw number*, you might want to refine this question.

Comment: @Shog9 unless we're talking about different links ([example of what I saw](http://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt?tab=activity&sort=reviews)), I can only see all kinds of reviews "mixed" together. By the way, I recently made a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220522) to also make this data (total amount of all reviews "mixed" and couple other review related stats for candidates) easier accessible for voters convenience

Comment: Oh, good - I'll answer there.

Comment: -1 for the hand drawn circle.  +1 for the stick figure.  +1 for asking for information about participation in the janitorial aspects of the site.  Handling close votes quickly is important as it provides useful information to people asking questions on the site.  Net: +1.

Comment: As the moderator queue for questions seems to pile up, much like the closed vote questions queue, I think this is a great test. A moderator of the site will be handling things that have been brought to someone's attention already, and the stats on the closed question queue seem to be a good indicator of their ability to process a large queue.

Comment: Re: "Update: over 100 upvotes, not bad for a question accused of being `not relevant to a mod's duties` " questions about politicians’ religions are pretty popular too

Comment: @RichardTingle note that ["review history" links on election posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220624/165773) were purposely exposed last year by SE team for all candidates, do you think that was done for a popularity reasons?

Comment: @gnat Yes, but thats to get a look at how people actually have reviewed. Rather than their opinions on what should be done about it, or the raw number (as opposed to the quality)

Comment: some comments under this question taught me new ways to sweep the issues under the carpet. Guess if it was technically possible to [close an answer as a duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195352/daily-close-votes-queue-limit#comment615699_195355 "'...and pretend the problem doesn't exist'"), it would have been attempted too

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Even though the question isn't concerned with the specific duties of a mod, I think it's a great question for measuring a person's work ethic - so-to-speak. After thinking about it, I decided if *any* candidate answered with a skimpy #, it'd be a sure no-vote.  I mean, how lazy and truly uninterested are you?  IMHO, seeing that number makes me think there are a whole lot of people who need to spend more time making worthy contributions to the site, and less time voting to close.  Honestly, what's the point of the vote if it never gets reviewed?

Comment: I only upvoted this because my gravatar is in the screenshot

Answer (score 112):

How would you deal with complaints about a user successfully suggesting a large number of low-quality edits?

Comment: This one's a bit broad... one man's low-quality edit can be a grammar nazi's obligation.

Comment: @Ian that's part of what makes it a good question. How the candidate interprets the question can give significant insight in to their thought process and attitudes towards moderation. And it's nice to know if they recognize the truth in what you've said as well.

Comment: @Ian what I had in mind specifically was people adding tags like "for-loop" to years old questions in order to gain the 2 rep points.... But as Esoteric says, a general response will give us an idea of the candidate's mindset

Comment: How do you know that they are doing it to gain 2 rep points?  Maybe they are just pedantic about tags.  (I hate people calling others out for "trawling for points".)  A better definition of low quality edit might be when they correct 3 mistakes and leave 5 more uncorrected (and I have been guilty of that myself!).

Comment: @Pëkka This seems upside down to me. If there's something wrong with giving x rep points for edits, then that's where the problem is. Either we accept that even minor edits get x rep points, or we don't. If we don't we should change the rules, that's all.

Comment: @KubaOber but I'm talking about nonsensical edits that *lower* the quality of the post.

Answer (score 107):

What's your take on [link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) that get flagged for not being answers? Should they be removed when flagged, or are they worth keeping around if they answer the question?

Comment: As "meta" says, answer with a link is not an answer :) Keeping those will just encourage people to post more answers like that to promote their blogs or whatever. Besides, if the link is no longer valid, who will check that? (shrug)

Comment: Might be worth elaborating slightly on what sort of answers you're talking about, since true "link only" answers are quite rare.

Comment: @Shog9: I see your point. There might be something like "Your answer can be found here<link>." with the destination being a blog post. Or for the question "Does anybody have a link to <some obscure thing>" it might be a valid answer, but isn't it what we have search engines for and then the question should be downvoted for the lack of research and eventually be removed?

Comment: It should not be deleted as this might contain the useful information. Also those link answer should neither be allowed to be accepted as answer nor should get upvote. Though downvote should be allowed :D

Comment: @InderKumarRathore at Programmers, we've got like [48 such answers left](http://data.stackexchange.com/programmers/query/102718/marginal-short-answers-with-links?AnswerScoreMax=100&AnswerScoreMin=-100&AnswerLength=200 "having length below 200 chars") - _all time, any score_. All the rest has been mostly deleted. And guess what? [site is going and growing just fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773) without this sort of garbage

Comment: Any link should be accompanied by some explanation as to what the resource is and why it is applicable. If for no other reason to clarify that the posted answer is in earnest. If the standard for a question asked is effort and thought , shouldn't a posed answer be doubly so?

Comment: @kukido Issue of expired link valid. While original (germane) content ideal for answers, would content from an outside link that gets copy/pasted into SO with appropriate citation (url, date accessed, etc.) be acceptable? Seems that would retain quality of site content as well as give proper credit where due.

Comment: @ChaZu: If the relevant content is copied, then it will not be a "link-only answer" anymore. The links are not disallowed, the discussion is about "link-only answers", meaning - no text :-)

Comment: It's an excellent question, given that those answers really ought to be being flagged for being very low quality, not for not being answers at all. Link-only answers _can_ answer the question for now, but have no keeping quality.

Comment: @DonalFellows VLQ description says "answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing" which makes it a very (**very**) bad fit for link-only answers... ([this has been discussed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140066/165773))

Comment: @gnat: but then it's confusing having the "link only answer and not spam" canned comment available when selecting "recommend deletion" -- I can understand how someone can be confused.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy agree, it's confusing. [Link-only answers are slippery matters](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183603/165773) - that is, at SO, where neither **moderators**, nor SE team have made up their mind on them. In comparison, at Programmers this is a solved problem, [not an issue anymore](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220314/2014-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/220344?noredirect=1#comment716529_220344)

Comment: Again, the comments here are not the place to debate this. These questions are for the moderator candidates to formulate their own responses, not for how we would react if asked. There are other questions about this on Meta, if you want to move the arguments there.

Answer (score 94):

As a moderator, your votes become binding. Actions you used to take like flagging, closing, and deleting will take effect immediately without any input from any other users or moderators.

How will you adapt the way you currently flag and vote to deal with this change?

Comment: It's not only the obvious stuff that is binding too. Voting to 'Leave Open' a question from the review queue removes that question from the queue - moderator votes in reviews are binding too.

Answer (score 93):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Comment: *A diamond will be attached to everything you say **and have said**...* - thank you for this! I feel it may not occur to some. This is important for the community to consider as well: how do [you] feel about all of [nominee]'s activity labeled as coming from a **community-elected**, and essentially "endorsed," user? I suppose the results of the voting will answer that question, though.

Comment: @Trojan I imagine that since we're already at over 20 submissions, these bonus questions won't get asked lest someone posts them as a separate answer for review with the community's 8.

Comment: @GraceNote I think the 2nd "optional" question is an important one, so I've branched it off as a new answer.

Comment: @nhinkle's branched answer is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220314/2014-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/220436#220436) (who wants to Ctrl+F anyway?)

Answer (score 74):

**If you became a moderator, would your actions be more like an Exception Handler or a Janitor?**

To put it in other terms, do you think your moderation style will be more focused on allowing the community to run the site and you will only step in to handle exceptions, or do you think your style will be more focused on aggressively trying to "clean up" the site?

I realize a moderator's duties involve both roles, and that there is no right answer to this question. Identifying with either role is valid, and will appeal to different people.

Comment: This is an insightful distinction to make, although I think I'd be hard-pressed to judge where each current mod would fall. I'm not sure how the difference plays itself out publicly. Still, it's a question sure to get an interesting answer.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I hope it gets enough votes to get asked. I think both are perfectly valid moderation styles, and it gives voters a good idea of the person's moderation style. Also for me, the answer will greatly influence who I decide to vote for :)

Comment: FWIW, personally I serve both roles, but am far more interested in the passive equine exception handler approach. Some cleanup roles are very straightforward - delete 100 non-answers in a single minute. Others, not so much, especially in cases where people just don't seem to know how to flag.

Comment: I feel like this question is too leading. The tone leads the reader to want to answer this as "of course im a janitor" mostly because "going out of the way" is tied to it.

Comment: @Shawn I think that a moderator's duties include both roles, and am interested in finding out which role a moderator candidate will primarily identify themselves with, as it will likely tell me what their moderation style is. I think I see your point though, and perhaps we can reword it to be clear that either answer is equally acceptable.

Answer (score 65):

What are your views on the chat feature?

Do you plan to spend time in the chat once you're elected and assist in its moderation?

Comment: make http://cv-pls.com/backlog part of SO!

Comment: @crypticツ it's called the 'close vote queue' and it's not doing too well (unlike the cv backlog) - another issue for this election :D

Comment: @crypticツ - An API for searching? Have you tried google? It wont produce exactly who said what, but you can search phrases. For example, if you wanted to get a solid measure of how many wtfs were produced in a room you could google: `site:http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcripts/11 wtf` to see a wtf count for the php room :) C#'s is 2880 (I will let you figure out php's :D) [Serious portrayal of code review](http://s167866.gridserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/wtf.png)

Comment: @TravisJ Google won't even come close to what is needed when it comes to searching. You can hit me up in the PHP room for a detailed explanation if you want.

Comment: +1 Helping deal with questions about proper moderation and behavior affects things that my chat group cares about (like what a bot is allowed to do or not do, which has come up).  Being a chat user informs that.  Yet I might expand this also to *"how do you plan to make yourself personally available to moderate on a system that doesn't have messaging or provide contact information"*.  Will it be with chat?  Something else?

Comment: Also, we have a lot of positive experience with mods that are active in chat like ThiefMaster, Gordon, Minitech, BoltClock and a few others like Robert that come every now and then.

Answer (score 64):

Are you on drugs?

Comment: I hate to say it. But this is actually a legitimate question.

Comment: Also: "Have you ever been convicted of a criminal offense, felony or misdemeanor (exclusive of any marijuana related conviction over two years old;any conviction for which the record has been judicially ordered sealed, expunged, or statutorily eradicated; any misdemeanor conviction for which probation has been successfully completed or otherwise discharged and the case has been judicially dismissed; or any arrest for which a pretrial diversion program has been successfully completed? If yes, please state nature of offense(s), date(s), city and state and disposition."

Comment: Well I figure you'd have to be to run for SO mod ;0

Comment: This should not disqualify you, we just want to know who's holding.

Comment: Followup: Don't you think you should be?

Comment: Now rephrasing your **Q:** *"Do you see flying unicorns?"* **A:** *"I'm not on drugs."* `1.` Proof that he was diligently following Meta. `2.` He still needs a good pair of glasses. `3.` He's a liar.

Comment: Yes, this __such__ answer to __this__ question is a brilliant demonstration of how upvoting/downvoting system works.

Comment: That question is too personal and offensive. The moderators aren't NSA spions.

Comment: It's possible you missed the joke, @ŁukaszL. :) (Also, yes they are!)

Comment: There are many kind of drugs, those which are legal and those which are illegal. Drugs which are legal(treatment) and have an impact on the persons decisions and drugs which are illegal and have no effect on that whatsoever.

Comment: @JimmyKane: Are you suggesting that all illegal drugs have no effect on a person's decision-making abilities? That's an interesting viewpoint.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit not at all. The contrary. That all drugs legal or not can have affect. My problem is that drugs in general and this question should not be asked plain as this. I would prefer 2 seperate questions. One for illegal (highs) drugs and a second one referring to the treatment drugs. Something like: Are you on treatment and if yes are there any substances that this treatment requires that affect your decision etc. It's not polite to ask someone: "Are you on drugs?" (he might have a heart problem or something he does not want to discuss further).

Comment: I've known *looots* of people who took legal drugs recreationally - and quite a few who took illegal ones to treat specific medical conditions, @Jimmy. That said, you may be taking this too seriously.

Comment: @JimmyKane: OK I think I parsed your statement wrong. But yes, like ŁukaszL, you may have made the mistake of reading this as a serious suggestion ;) Consider the following question on SO: "sir,,,how can i make a cattle prod in VB6??? plz help me to solve this prlbme thx" My response is typically: "_are you on drugs?!_"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit haha seems legit with the cow. Yes I did the mistake :-( It's difficult to tell intentions via text only.

Comment: This is a legitimate concern. Many programmers are under the influence of Adderall and/or cocaine and booze. This could impair judgement and cause them to leave the site if they are arrested.

Comment: @JimmyKane: I aim to make it difficult ;)

Comment: What if there is a medical reason for it? My country doesn't have, but I do know some countries that use weed as medicine?

Comment: @rockinfresh: Read the comments above.

Comment: Why should we be entitled to know such personal details of a moderator on this site? Chances are they are more of a "public" figure than many of user base, therefore identifiable. Assuming simple case: legitimate, prescribed, medical use... why should they have to publicly declare any of that? Surely if they have demonstrated adequate competence in other criteria (social, technical) this is not something that really matters.

Comment: @ChaZu: I'll say the same thing to you as I did to the other likeminded contributors: _read the comments_.

Comment: Technically caffeine is a drug.

Comment: @Thundar: Technically SO is a drug

Answer (score 56):

A diamond will be attached to everything you say *and have said in the past*, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do (and have done) will be seen under a different light. How do you intend to handle that responsibility?

<sup>(Branched off from Grace Note's backup default questions list).</sup>

Comment: I'd vote for any candidate who promises to make it a heart instead.

Comment: @paddy: I'd be happy to make that promise, if you'll be understanding that moderators have no control whatsoever over that.

Answer (score 38):

All of you feel that being a moderator will make you much more effective than simply being a high-rep user.

What moderator ability, if any, do you think can be given to high-rep users instead to make the community in general more effective? If this ability was given to high-rep users, would you still want to become a moderator?

Answer (score 37):

In what situations should a moderator delete a question themselves?

Comment: Delete own question?

Comment: No, the sense is to use exclusive right of deletion (moderator can do that while in normal case it's required some votes from community) - i .e. in which cases that right should be used

Comment: They should not delete -  so people can learn and there is an opportunity to clarify the question if it has been misunderstood in any way.

Comment: Are there currently no guidelines on this?

Answer (score 34):

How would you handle a single user that is upset at a moderator action you have taken?

For example, if someone posted on meta "This mod deleted my [question|answer|comment] and he is abusing his power," how would you react?

Comment: I have been "that guy" and it was on one of the beta sites.

Comment: What does 'handle' mean? Would they reason with them, flame, ignore or retaliate? There isn't a working complaints procedure, so are you suggesting there should be one, or what?

Comment: @smci By that, I mean "how would you react"? What would you say?

Comment: My point to you is that 'talking things better' is not the only possible action, and some mods don't even do that. Are you satisfied that there is a functional complaints procedure for bad mod decisions? And specifically do mods with patterns of bad actions get sanctioned? I'm not.

Answer (score 32):

You see the question which was put on hold by another moderator (not with 5 votes of community). But you think that this question is good and should not be closed. What will you do?

Answer (score 32):

There are lots of people on StackOverflow, and their opinions on "how the site should work" also differ a lot.

**Some people are mainly driven by a desire to help and/or participate**; as a result, their activity might not be regarded as efficient or even desirable when viewed under a certain light. For example, they might choose to answer a question even though it has been obviously (to a regular) asked and answered before.

For these people, directly helping another member has immensely more value than clicking buttons (which they might still do, the two actions are certainly not mutually exclusive).

On the other end of the scale, **some people are driven by StackOverflow's "one quality answer site to rule them all" aspirations**; as a result, their activity might stick to the letter of the law and make it harder for others to get the answer they came here for. For example, they might downvote/delvote questions *and* answers because the answer already exists and therefore another one might be detrimental to a future seeker's ability to discover the canonical version.

For these people, maintaining the site's knowledge base has immensely more value than handholding a newbie (which again, they might do).

Given that both of these groups are entitled to their place in the sun and in fact have to cooperate in order for maximum value to be produced,

> How do you intend to moderate both these types of do-gooders so that
>   everyone goes home satisfied at the end of the day rather than
>   deciding that SO is full of undesirables? Do you have a strong opinion
>   of your own on the matter? How will it affect your stance as a moderator?

Comment: I think the grey line here is that sometimes old answers are dated and the old answers no longer apply, or are partial answers.

Comment: @Jon One of the most important questions for me. I think it's a red herring to think there is not a way both sides can win. *(Wait, I'm not running for moderator, am I supposed to answer the question?)* There's a big difference between clicking "close as duplicate" vs. getting medieval with silent downvotes (or noisy snark) on someone who may be a kid in a distant country, on a 300 baud modem, struggling with their first post to an English-speaking site. To me, a moderator must actively care about discerning spam from beginners. Ignore that concern and I won't care about this site anymore.

Comment: @HostileFork: I certainly did not want to imply that it's a contest with a single winner! My concern is that, as in all democracies, different groups have different priorities yet all of them must somehow be accommodated -- a balance must be struck.

Comment: Best question I've read so far.

Answer (score 30):

You see a Meta post calling out a user for spamming the site with edits containing referral links. After checking the details, you notice that this is not your typical spammer. Instead, the user has more than 2000 reputation (and thus also able to edit posts directly).

Because of the rather nasty kind of spamming - adding his spam to posts from reputable users - people call for the user to be deleted immediately. How will you deal with this situation?

Comment: Deleting that user? That's kind of harsh. His account could have just been hijacked.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk: this is a potential question for nominees to answer (much like how we have example questions in Area 51 proposal definitions), not an actual question posed to everyone.

Answer (score 29):

What is, in your opinion as a potential future moderator, the biggest problem that Stack Overflow currently faces? If you were to get elected, what actions would you take towards resolving these issues?

Comment: This seems too vague

Comment: It's purposefully vague to provoke thought and reveal as much information about our candidates as possible

Comment: The candidates already stated similar comments in the nominations, so this would be redundant.

Answer (score 26):

While the moderator position you're nominating yourself for is a voluntary position, there is a minimum amount of time that you would need to be available in order to be an effective moderator.

How much time would you be able to spend on mod duties at Stack Overflow, and are there any known circumstances in which this will change in the future?

Comment: Should we make a point of differentiating between "time spent on SO" vs "time spent on mod duties on SO"?

Comment: @Rachel Definitely.

Answer (score 23):

Based on my experiences and observations as a mod, I believe that a new mod should prepare to commit to devoting one hour per day, 5 days per week to handling flags in the flag queue, *for the first year.*  Here's why:

1. Stack Overflow raises somewhere between 1000 and 2000 flags per day
2. During any given time, only about 25% of the mods on Stack Overflow are *actively moderating* (we currently have sixteen mods, which means our active base is four).
3. The period of maximum productivity for new mods seems to be the first year.  After that, a certain degree of burnout sets in (let's be honest).
4. It takes about an hour to handle 100 flags, once you gain some experience.  The top performers handle 200 to 300 flags per day.  Currently, we need to be processing about 200 more flags per day, and there are three open moderator slots.

Would you be able to make such a commitment?

Answer (score 21):

How would you deal with SO users with a revenge oriented mentality?
(Down voting questions and/or answers of others, those down voted or commented on them)

Comment: There isn't much that they *can* do, even if they wanted to, at least in almost all situations.  Even mods don't have enough visibility into who voted for whom to take guesses at this, nor can they know why someone voted any more than you or I can.  There are cases of serial voting that can be addressed, but the script handles almost all of that.

Comment: [so] supposedly already has algorithms in place to deal with serial downvoting

Comment: But if someone planned to do that in a time interval, what to do in that case?

Answer (score 21):

If a post has thousands of views and at least +50 upvotes, why would it be a good or bad idea to put it under a historical lock instead of deleting it?

Given:

- The question itself is off topic or out of scope (regardless of when the community came to its senses)
- The answers are obsolete, or so many that two-thirds are variations/duplicates on the first set of answers posted.

Comment: Every time a Hacker News comment cries about a question being closed an angel of ►☼◄ gets its wings

Comment: More important: what are the alternatives? For example, converting the whole topic into community blog entry...

Answer (score 21):

You've had a bad day at work/home/school. How do you make sure you don't unfairly take it out on poor innocent posts/users?

Comment: It's a good question but one of those questions you often can't get an honest answer about. We all think we're better, calmer, or more in control than we actually are under the influence of emotions. Probably better to get a feel for this  indirectly through answers to other questions.

Answer (score 19):

Describe your perfect day. (This is a trick question, the only correct answer is to "Flag as off topic").

In all seriousness, questions that have been edited more than 10 times by the asking party are converted to community wikis. Do you think it is appropriate to rollback the community wiki status upon request? Further, what is your opinion of this policy in general (do you see as punishing the asker for improving the question)?

Comment: Would the down-voter mind explaining their reasoning? Did the levity in the first part of the question bother you? I thought this was a pretty valid question...

Answer (score 18):

Let's consider this situation.

You happened to close a question on Stack Overflow but the close reason wasn't very much acceptable. The OP brings up that issue on Meta where the community feels that it was wrongly closed. Another moderator walks by and opens the question, suggesting that your action was indeed questionable.

"How/What" would you, as a Moderator, "react/respond/do" in such a situation?

Comment: "proving"? That sounds like you are throwing the balance in one direction.

Comment: @ypercube - I didn't look into the words I was using that much. Thanks for bringing it to my notice :) I hope it sounds better now :)

Answer (score 16):

Frequently it is noticed that some users who are active in the review queues on Stack Overflow are merely clicking "No Action" or "Accept". As a moderator, what action is appropriate to take against these so-called "robo-reviewers", and would you be willing to investigate instances such as these and take that action?

Comment: I think this could be more useful if rephrased. Currently, the answer is "Yes" or "No." While most candidates would probably expand on that, it could be more revealing to ask *how* they would do so, or *why* they wouldn't (if applicable in each case).

Comment: Feel free to edit

Answer (score 16):

Real-time case:

A desperate user has posted the same question (some borderline between programming and configuration) to many SE sites. The problem is badly defined, but there are SCREAMINGS that this is URGENT and he BEGS FOR HELP.

The user is surely aware that posting his question everywhere to increase the chance of getting an answer is a bit of an egoistic behavior, but he thinks his problem is more important than the others.

How would you deal with such users? What measures would you take:

- simply closing as off-topic and informing that is off-topic and why
- downvoting
- comments informing that such behavior is unacceptable
- spam flags or any other attempts to block such user
- something else?

Comment: How's this a **moderator** topic? Regular users should do all these

Answer (score 16):

A user calls you out on Meta, screaming bloody murder over an action you felt was completely justified. They probably get some responses from the folks on Meta before you even learn there is an issue, but even if the community agrees your decision was perfectly fine, the user will sometimes be disgruntled and move on to other places (their blog, Reddit, Twitter) calling you all sorts of terrible things, and by your full name. (And if you were actually *mistaken* in your decision, then may God have mercy on your soul.)

It *will* most likely happen to you. There is no way to avoid it,  no matter how carefully you moderate.

This aspect of moderation takes a certain amount of thick skin. Do you have it? What would you do if a conflict with a user "gets to you"?

Answer (score 15):

A new user has arrived and doesn't really understand the way the Stack Exchange system is supposed to work. They're complaining that people keep editing their posts and a roll back war has started on a question that they've asked.

You need to step in and moderate the situation. What actions do you take?

Comment: I think a more general question about keeping the whole community informed about the rules and guidelines is due here. Because it is not only new users who misuse SO. This is again, not because these users are bad, they are just not informed.

Answer (score 15):

What would your stance be on educating new users on how to ask questions, and the consequences of asking too many poor-quality questions?

The growth of the Close Votes queue and the frequency of [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) type questions here on Meta seem to indicate that we're not in an ideal position on that front.

Although we *do* have resources such as [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (and many wonderful others), do you think we could do more to help newer users take advantage of them? Or do you think we are already doing enough as a community, and should hold new users accountable for not already taking full advantage of the resources at their disposal?

Answer (score 13):

How would you handle the balance between moderator enforcements and community self-moderation? What would you do in case of community disagreement with the moderator's actions and vice versa - how would you handle situations when the community is consistently doing something against the guidelines? In your opinion, should the rules be imposed on the community or community should form the rules? All in all, what is the right balance for it?

Answer (score 11):

You are **not** elected as a moderator. How will this influence your participation on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Have there historically been any issues along these lines? If not, this isn't a biggie is it?

Comment: I certainly see users now pop-up out of nowhere and I've seen them disappear as well. This question (if it was selected) would have had the potential to reveal who really is a true member of the community.

Comment: Uhuh but I think participation is just one of many useful [metrics](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221593/162570) on candidates which could be added - see my question.

Comment: I wasn't referring to 'participation' as a metric more as a behaviour/attitude thingy.

Comment: Indeed, but since it can be measured, and is somewhat illuminating, why not?

Answer (score 10):

What is your philosophy regarding when a moderator should take action, versus allowing the community to moderate itself?  And how would you handle a situation when you personally think a question should be reopened after the community has closed it?

Answer (score 9):

**As a moderator, What is your take on People behaving somewhat rude on the newbies asking for help** ?

I see a lot of new users don't post about their effort, existing code. People (including me sometimes) ask "What have you tried ?". It may appear rude to OP. It is in the rule book of SE that you should do your homework first before asking question on stackoverflow or other stack exchange sites but new users may not be aware about that.

Answer (score 9):

I see a lot of duplicate answers pop up. Some at the same time, but some are a long time after the first answer.

What are your views on answers, that are just copies of answers provided 10's of minutes before?

Comment: Kind of curious actually. My understanding was that non-mods could flag them for moderator attention; it'd be nice to see what'll probably happen if it's thrown over and said candidate sees the flag.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a situation:

A person sees a comment (from another person) that offers a (sort of) correct answer for the question. He doesn't understand it well, yet he posts it as answer in the hopes of gaining a lot of +10's.

Now, that answer is partially right (it's been copied!). What would you do to that answer? Removing it means leaving the question answerless. Keeping it would mean a low quality answer and unfair to the one who posted the right comment. I've seen such situations, even though I haven't been on SE for long.

Comment: +1 for the same thing what I was thinking. But this is not only `reputation hungry newbie`. There are too many members who ask a question and accept an answer which is completely different from the question or answer given by his friend to increase his points. Some time I asked the reason (because I have given the answer also), and got reply as this was perfect for me :).

Answer (score 7):

You finally made it and got elected as a moderator! But just barely, with a couple of votes over the needed limit, and there are many people that are against you being a moderator. There are even comments like "If that guy gets a diamond, I will leave SO forever".

How will this influence your actions as a moderator?

In particular, what are you going to do (if anything) to try to prevent "That guy deleted my question just because I didn't want him to be a moderator. Now see how right I was with that!" reactions; how do you deal with such reactions?

Answer (score 5):

Have you ever been banned (temporaryily) from SO?

Some naughty behavior on SO can lead to a temporary ban for a user. 
For instance, failing too many review audits may cause a user to be banned frrom reviewing for a short time.
Also fiddling with the voting system, like serial up/down voting can put a user on a temporary suspension.

Have you ever been banned? if so, why?

Comment: This is somewhat problematic. Is this information puplic? If not theres nothing to stop people lying, if so theres no point asking

Comment: @RichardTingle I don't think we can stop people from lying. But I think we can give them a chance to come clean with some misconduct that happened in the past.

Comment: I don't think being banned for failed review audits (especially at the beginning on SO) really means much. What's more important is whether a person learnt from that.

Answer (score 5):

A user asks a question that seems relatively off-topic with the Stack Overflow questioning context(not a mainly coding question), but is a question that concerns many members and receives many upvotes and even more, many good answers (measured by upvotes too).
As a new moderator, What do you do and how do you react?

Comment: What sort if question would it be? I ask because many non coding questions are still on topic. Such as usage of tools commonly used by programmers

Comment: Take a small example. This question can be considered as of non-coding, asking for opinions. But it has many good answers and upvotes on them, even on the question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107019/how-do-you-know-if-you-are-a-bad-programmer-or-how-do-you-tell-someone-they-are

Comment: @NickL. I don't think that is a good example.  That question, regardless of the votes, is incredibly out of scope.  It's just seeking opinions, so I hope the response from the potential mod is "close, lock, and delete"

Comment: That exactly is my point, that this one is out of scope, but has many positive votes and therefore, some liked by community, answers.

Answer (score 5):

You start handling a flag which you tend to agree with (e.g. NAA, low quality etc) and right before you click the delete button (or even worse) you notice the offender is a friend of yours in real life.

What are you going to do? Delete action is public and he/she will see what you did and might be upset... in the real life. What takes precedence?

Comment: Pull hand off mouse. Pick up phone. Call friend in real life. Ask "Guess what I'm doing right now?" Put hand back on mouse. Then answer "Cleaning up your mess!" Click delete and say "Check your SO notifications, biatch!?"

Comment: Does it depend on whether that user (or their friends) have >3K rep and will know it was you or not?

Answer (score 4):

How would you deal with a user that gets upset on your comments to his question (poking to improve) and **flags** your comments for *moderator attention* ?

Answer (score 3):

How much percentage of time which you currently devote for Q & A will be reserved for moderation.

If you are selected, Will you be contributing in Q & A with same efficiency as you are doing currently?

Comment: Why should this be a criterion for the election? It's just background information. Would you ever not vote for a good candidate primarily because you feared they would contribute less Q&A as a result?

Answer (score 3):

A longtime user (20k+ rep trusted) and a relatively new user (say 1k rep) get into a disagreement over an answer. The veteran clearly feels that the new user's answer is wrong (think of the difference as pot-ay-to vs po-tah-to). The thread ends with the new user's answer being accepted, even though the veteran's answer was also correct.

Later the new user complains about mysterious downvotes and notes the veteran seems to be shadowing them in threads. There's nothing overtly wrong being done here but, as a moderator you look into it and see that there seems to be a distinct pattern of downvotes going on, even on answers that don't seem to warrant it.

How do you handle it?

Comment: Is this currently autodetected? Or not if they keep the serial downvoting below some threshold?

Answer (score 3):

You Found a Funny Question by a new user , Just in hope to get upvoted and get some reputation , as a moderator what will be your first Action?

Comment: I'd add to this - what if the question had only just been asked and has no votes or answers, compared to what if it's been open for hours and had a lot of votes and answers.

Comment: Does the question make a reasonable question in a funny way, or is it fully a joke question

Comment: That is a joke, just for up votes from tense programmers to make them laugh and in pleasure click up vote button

Answer (score 2):

I have seen many legitimate first posts flagged for various reasons, and there can be a fine line between setting the filter too tight for legitimate new users vs too lax for spam or troll users.

What actions do you think best separate out these two groups, and what should moderators do better in order to encourage new, unfamiliar users while discouraging trolls and spam?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of sites with similar subject matter to Stack Overflow, perhaps with overlapping user bases and questions - Computer Science, Software Quality Assurance & Testing, Programming Puzzles & Code Golf, Code Review, Database Administrators, Information Security, Programmers, Game Development, and more. Cross-posting and poor migrations are a problem, especially for the communities still in Beta. What do you plan on doing to help educate users who cross-post? What about users who suggest that questions be cross-posted, especially without understanding the expectations about the other communities? And finally, as a moderator, understanding these other communities yourself so that you can migrate (or not migrate) effectively?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there will be edits which have the below case.

A reviewer thinks it should be rejected and clicks reject. But to his surprise he will get a message saying this edit already approved.

How would you handle such cases. because useless edits take place and will be approved.

Comment: I'm not really clear on how this involves a moderator to be honest.

Comment: This is not regarding the honesty of moderators but the fruit fullness and validity of reviews done.

Comment: I mean like what would be done once a moderator is involved that wouldn't happen if a moderator wasn't involved?

Answer (score 1):

(Based on [some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem/9758#9758) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158418/careless-review-upvotes-are-actively-contributing-to-the-quality-problem-not-co) on meta and my opinion too)

There is an issue with voting system in SO. The **supposed** problem is that voting isn't working well in answers/questions that:

- Already have many upvotes/downvotes. That means: if user is visiting question with 20+ voted answer - good chances are that he'll upvote that answer *just because it already has high rate*. Same goes with downvote
- Were posted *"too late"*. There are many questions, answers to which may be done with short explanation and 1-2 links to manual pages (but still that answers may be good) - but, in the same time, answer may involve explanation of CS theory, some deep research e.t.c. - i.e. definitely better than short answers, but takes much longer time to be written. Obviously, good chances are - "fast answer" will get more upvotes, just *because it's fast*

Since you'll be a moderator, I want to ask - do you think that this **supposed** problem is actually a problem? How do you feel about this and what may be your suggestions?

*Not to be included in question to moderator*

It's obvious, that points above may not be treated as problem. And they are not related to *moderation* directly. But since moderators are supposed to be "leaders of the community" - I want to know their feelings about issues above. So it's my point to ask them about that - because it's very important for me (even in this thread we can see samples of "fastest answers in the West" or "upvoted just because" - in my opinion)

Comment: I know you've already said it but this has nothing to do with moderation. In fact a moderator should not have any view (in their official capacity) as to how people should be voting (obviously they're users too; in which capacity they can have whatever view they like)

Comment: @RichardTingle - yes, you're right in that. I'm relying on the fact, that this thread is intended to be collection of question to moderators - from wide range of viewpoints. That is why I think that general SO questions (i.e. community management or organization of system itself) is connected to goals of moderators, among which I see "development & improving of SO". Thank you for your feedback - so, while I totally agree, I think moderator should have clear vision in which direction SO should move and be developed. That's why I've posted this question. I see it's important for me.

Answer (score 1):

How will you handle a flagged or closed question that is about a topic way out of your knowledge. For example, if the question is kind of technical and regarding to some weird esotheric programming language (like Brainfuck), and you don't know anything about it. What will you do?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever country you are from, you will be expected to moderate a site with global reach. While all operations might be conducted in English, **its user base includes people with different cultural norms and values from your own**. How do you expect to deal with different kinds of reactions to moderator actions and how will you determine the best way to communicate this site's values to those whose background is different than your own? What equips you for this task?

Answer (score 1):

In order to give voters more insight into candidates' moderating styles, what specific set of additions/changes should be made to the **metrics on each candidate**?

In particular:
During an election we see all sorts of claims being thrown around by and against candidates about people's historical actions.
To the majority of us users who don't devote a large part of their life to the daily drama on SO, this is a useless and aggravating insider debate with unverifiable claims. Certainly it provides no insight.
So what (aggregated) metrics should be added/changed in order to gives users a quick and objective picture of a candidate's behavior?
e.g.

- aggregated % of time you vote-to-close, vote-to-keep-open, etc.
- aggregated % of time you uphold flags (broken out by category)
- what % of a mod's votes-to-close were overturned/rejected?
- your recommendations here?

Note: any such metrics would be aggregated (and thresholded) to preserve individual anonymity.

Answer (score 0):

How do you balance your time between Stack Overflow and your other commitments? How will becoming a community moderator change that balance and do you have any changes coming in the foreseeable future (for example new job, baby on the way, etc) that will change that?

Answer (score 0):

How would you deal with new users who follow posting habits mandated by other sites but which are unacceptable here? For example, many fora like official PrimeFaces forum require user to post **complete classes and JSF pages**, because their users like to be able to copy the whole code into IDE and launch; whereas SO likes the code to be as minimalistic as possible.

So we have a user that posts the whole assignment (from uni, workplace etc., it doesn't matter here), post the whole code they have written, in effect his post is a big **wall of code** taking multiple browser pages to read. At the end or in comments he specifies what he really doesn't understand/what is the problem here, so it's **not a help vampire**, but someone who doesn't know how to post.

The question: **how do you deal with it**?

As a moderator you could simply **delete** the question to prevent heart attack/browser collapse by other users. You could immediately **close** the question, **providing comment** what is wrong here, or **expecting user to find out himself why question was closed**, if he cares enough. You could also **edit** the question yourself or write a comment you will **reopen the question** when the edit would make that question more readable. Or you could do something else.

Comment: I think I get your point here, but we like "complete classes" here too, just *small* complete classes

Comment: Why is this a question for a moderator? And why isn't there an answer "D. None of the above". As users, we should be commenting on those kind of posts ourselves, and often times, the user does correct his own post when he's pointed out his mistake.

Comment: @Stephan-Branczyk: because many SO users in fact don't make helpful comment, they start flaming/downvoting/flagging/voting-to-close/dissing the poster. In cases of abuse, beating up on newbies for sport is a consequence-free environment; some tag categories are worse than others. There are some very prominent repeat offenders. It's a site problem and moderators have a role in fixing it. It's about leadership, not just the very narrow question of whether the mod helps edit the post or not.

Comment: @Smci, We can all make mistakes, but it's important to reference concrete examples of the mistakes we make. Let's try to agree on what we consider to be the problems first, because we don't all hang around the same tag categories and we obviously don't have the same reference points.

Answer (score 0):

What action(s) would you take if it was brought to your attention or you saw that a particular user was trolling every answer on a question leaving what most would consider to be rude, non-constructive comments, where they just wanted to point out that everyone was wrong to be antagonistic in drawing out arguments for argument's sake?

Comment: Surely this is basic stuff that would be automatically dealt with by flagging, and ultimately some sanction against the user if they do this on many Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

What would you do if someone flagged your question or posted a *partly offensive* (you think it is offensive, but **generally** it isn't) comment about you?

Comment: Mind if you elaborate? What situation do you have in mind?

Comment: E.g. somebody wrote *partly offensive* (you think it is offensive, but **generally** it isn't) comment about you. Or someone's flag of your own question.

Comment: FYI: only another mod can able to review it.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a mistake, everybody can, or misunderstand something and take an action. Will you act like nothing happened and cover it or will you try to fix it somehow?

Answer (score -1):

In your eyes, what are the tasks of a Moderator? Which, if any, tasks do you see as more important than others? And, given access to the moderation tools, which parts/tasks do you plan on accomplishing? How do you plan on accomplishing these tasks? Be specific.

Comment: This is similar to one of the [generic question set][1] questions, but I am suggesting this to not just cover what a moderator does, but to incite more detailed responses, allowing the community to understand how a moderator sees their job and goals, instead of getting a job description as an answer.


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220315/188638

Comment: Full markdown isn't supported in comments to include a link you need to use mini markdown, it can also get upset if the http:// is missing. You include a link in the following way: `[generic question set](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220315/188638)` which gives [generic question set](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220315/188638)

Comment: @RichardTingle, thank you. It's been too long to edit my comment, but I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score -1):

What would be the **first** thing you would do if a user, who has just recently gained the tag edit privilege, had been mass removing a tag from questions, and most of time without any justification?

- Would you review all the edits one by one?
- Find a way to remove him this privilege?
- Contact someone from SO to help you rollback all of his edits with a script?

Answer (score -2):

In your opinion what is the single most important function of Moderators?

Answer (score -2):

Do you help those users who are struggling to articulate their questions?

Meaning English language is not native for most of the users, how do you help them? and have you improved any post before ?

Answer (score -2):

- Which of the least-moderated but still popular tags would you bring experience to?

I tried to create a query using this start point: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/148022/moderator-downvotes-this-month , but got stuck on splitting the tags in a post. Could someone help if this is a popular question?

Comment: Moderators aren't elected to bring domain knowledge to the table.  Moderators tasks are specifically designed to not require domain knowledge.

Comment: @Servy Agreed that this is the case for the most part. But I do think domain knowledge in tags is relevant when trying to quickly arbitrate conflicts. Further, many mods specifically speak to a desire to improve specific tags or have a passion for topics which has driven their participation on the site.

Comment: Part of evaluating a mod is determining if they're qualified to arbitrate conflicts when they *don't* have domain knowledge.  As for improving specific tags, that's certainly fine, but generally that's not going to be something they're doing *as a moderator*.  Tag cleanup actions are generally *non-moderator* actions.  Mods can certainly do them, but it's not one of their duties, and one doesn't need to be a mod to do them.

Answer (score -3):

What strategies would you recommend for creating canonical FAQs / wiki answers to mitigate the ever-present problem of people asking similar-but-not-identical questions, where the poster may not see the similarity with other potential duplicates (or not find it with a cursory search)?

I'm talking about cases where people ask a specific question about a generalised problem, but we don't have a good candidate to merge to which the OP will understand is a generalisation of their problem

This is something I see a lot of on tags i'm active in, including `facebook-*` where many first-time programmers are trying to hack together examples using sample code or documentation and are encountering problems because they don't understand the code they're working with

Comment: This is generally a problem that users within a given tag community need to resolve, rather than an issue for moderators.  It is up to the users to provide high quality canonical answers (and high quality canonical questions to go with them, if they don't come up naturally) rather than site moderators.

Comment: Fair point, but I think moderators taking an interest in such strategies and initiatives improves the overall site quality significantly

Comment: +1 This is an excellent suggestion which would both improve the site and reduce mod workload and reduce the close-queue. And mods should certainly take leadership where noone else is. @Servy, there are instances where tag communities don't do this, and they need a serious boot up the ass. Why should moderator workload be needlessly increased due to community activity around some nuisance tags being a mess? Taking this further, why not compile a **nuisance index of tags** in terms of average-moderator-workload-generated-per-question, and list the top-ten offenders?

Comment: @smci Quite simply if the users within a tag aren't interested in doing this, a mod isn't going to be *capable* of doing much.  The mods are unlikely to be the most qualified to be writing most of the canonical posts in a given tag, they aren't going to be able to keep the list of questions up to date on their own, nor are they going to be able to close all of the duplicate questions if the tag community encourages re-answering such questions rather than closing as a duplicate of a canonical.  A mod just isn't *capable* of solving this problem without enthusiastic community involvement.

Comment: @Servy you're not aware of communities around specific tags that cause needless drama and don't clean their own messes? Why not draw up a list of nuisance tags and give those communities an ultimatum to either start doing the business, or those topics will be banned (instant-close) until such time as they do?

Comment: @smci Because even the tags that have such reputations still do generate lots of quality content.  Perhaps not as much as could be desired, and there may be a higher ratio of noise along with it, but there still is helpful content in there that would be lost, and that would be a *significant* loss to have it all banned.  That's also a very, very good way to drive away basically *all* of the experts in those areas, pushing them to other sites.  I can't think of an easier way to kill the communities entirely.  That wouldn't help anything.

Comment: @Servy: no, like I said, it's only an extreme measure you take in extremis to tag communities that are generating too much moderator workload by failing to set down basic standards, answer wikis, FAQs etc.

Answer (score -3):

In your opinion is it more important for a moderator to have:

- a broader shallower knowledge and try to spread their time across more categories of questions
- a deeper narrower knowledge and spending most of their time in that domain only.

Comment: This shouldn't matter.  Moderators are not expected to have detailed knowledge of the subject matter.

Comment: @Robert Harvey but how did they get the reputation initially that made them a moderator?  By being a moderator, I think that there is an implication that they are skilled in some area of the site.

Comment: Certainly they would have enough skill to obtain the necessary reputation, yes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would argue that MOST moderator duties do not require domain knowledge, but some things such as approving code edits for low rep users should need some domain knowledge to ensure the quality of the answer (from a technical viewpoint) is not going backwards.

Comment: @m2o2r2g2 Reviewing suggested edits isn't a task for moderators.  Non-moderators review suggested edits.  For those rare suggested edits requiring domain knowledge, it is up to the non-moderator domain experts to evaluate those suggested edits.

Answer (score -3):

Do you think giving permanent bans is okay? Maybe you think everybody has to have always one more chance?

Comment: Permanent (or extremely long) bans aren't a thing anymore. The maximum suspension length a moderator can set is one year.

Answer (score -3):

A moderator's job is not easy, how do you expect to balance moderating two (or more) StackExchange sites efficiently? Wouldn't it be better to only allow a user to moderate one site?

If you aren't already a moderator, what are your thoughts on the statement below.

**A user should not be allowed to moderate more than one stack exchange site.**

Comment: If they aren't already a moderator, then what relevance is this question to them?

Comment: So, because you claim a moderator's job isn't easy, there's no way someone can moderator more than one site effectively?  Tell that to [this person](http://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf).

Comment: By stretching a moderator's resources across two sites you are effectively halving their efficiency. How can they do the job better than someone who can dedicate ALL their resources to the job? Won't they be decreasing their effectiveness on the site they already moderate?

Comment: To put this in perspective, Stack Overflow probably raises more flags every day than all other SE sites *combined.*

Comment: Moderators and the Stack Exchange team are the only people who can judge meaningfully whether being a mod on multiple sites is doable or not. I don't see the point in everyone else discussing it.

Comment: @Servy: Yeah, I know about that.  I was this was referring to non-SE people.

Answer (score -3):

What makes you think you can be a good moderate, I mean any thing other than reputation, helpful flags, etc. What if you lose your interest at some point; How will you deal with that situation.

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for non-code.

Answer (score -4):

How would you propose improving the question system to better promote quality answers and reduce the number of 'white noise' questions?

Comment: You don't need to be a mod to make such a proposal.  If any of the candidates knew of some magic bullet to effectively promote quality answers and reduce the number of low quality questions I would seriously hope they'd suggest it on meta regardless of whether they become a mod or not.  Of course, such magic bullets are very hard to come up with, so them not having an answer would generally be expected, in my mind.

Comment: And perhaps that would be a good answer from a potential moderator if you hadn't posted it here : /

Comment: My point remains that you're *very* unlikely to get any really useful answers, nor much in the way of insight from the candidates from this question.  They'll all be dodging the question in some way or another, you'll just be judging how effectively they dodge it.  There are so many more constructive questions about how they would actually moderate the site that would be more useful to voters.

Comment: That's why this is a site that utilizes voting to decide on the best questions to ask the moderators...  Everyone has an opinion that they should be able to share, and if it isn't seen as popular by others it gets brushed under the carpet...

Comment: Yes, and that's why I'm posting a comment explaining the problems with the question; to help inform future readers of why they shouldn't upvote this post.  Saying that the community will vote on posts doesn't mean we aren't allowed to discuss our opinions of the question, or how useful it is.

Answer (score -5):

- What is your goal as a moderator?
- Why do you require special privileges to attain it?
- What is lacking in your current status?

The above can be combined in the following loaded question:

> Assuming that each moderator wannabe expects to produce positive
>   effect to SO community, what will your contribution be and why can't
>   you do the same in your current status without additional privileges?

Comment: Split these up. Otherwise which one are we voting for?

Comment: @random - I actually consider my post as a single (obviously loaded) question.  In my mind these questions are inter-dependent.  I will post the clarification.

Answer (score -5):

Do you see yourself more as a person who specializes in one (or a few) specific topics, and will spend the majority of your time there, or someone who consistently moves around different topics, and offers help and guidance (be it programming, or SE use) across the board?

Answer (score -6):

What will you not do when you will be Moderator?

Comment: Incredibly vague question.

Answer (score -7):

Would you spend some of your *reputation* on bounties to encourage others to provide good solutions, or to reward existing answers?

Comment: This is not part of a moderator's duties.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I know it isn't, it's just for _personality analysis_ purposes.

Answer (score -9):

Someone whom you did not like in the past or who might have opposed to your comments/answers earlier, would that by any means influence his profile - deleting posts, flags, down votes?

Comment: Anyone who answered "revenge!" or similar should be disqualified on sheer stupidity

Comment: Yea but it would be interesting to know what answer does one give to this. Anyways this is gonna be diplomatic!

Answer (score -12):

If you were given the position of moderating Stack Overflow, **what would your short, long, and stretch goals be for yourself as a person, yourself as a moderator, and Stack Overflow as a community?**

To rephrase,

You will most likely find yourself learning as you go. How will you measure (from the experience of being a moderator) your personal development, your community contributions, and community development in the future?

Answer (score -19):

**[What is the Goal of “Hot Network Questions”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions)**

> what the heck we are actually trying to achieve...
>
> The list of questions from a variety of sites is in a great location screen-wise, it is readily accessible and does get a lot of eyes on it. But as with any marketing, the goal isn't just to grab eyes, it's to grab the right eyes...
>
> So what are the right eyes? What type of people do we want to attract to our site? What would we determine as 'success'? How can we measure that success?
>
> Please do not limit yourself to the very narrowly scoped topic above. Think outside the box if you'd like. On every page across the network we have a nice piece of real estate for showing off the rest of the network. How can that space best be used if not on a list of questions picked by an arbitrary algorithm?

Comment: Is this really something that matters on SO?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards nice piece of "screen real estate"? you bet

Comment: But is it really something that should matter to a moderator? They have no say in "political" decisions concerning the site (Edit: ah, I guess they may be able to influence the formula.)

Comment: @Pëkka per my reading of [The Anatomy of a Hot Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217573/the-anatomy-of-a-hot-question), it sure does

Comment: On any other site I'd agree @gnat, but SO has 6.7 _million_ visits a day... a hundred thousand people arriving from the rest of the network would barely be noticed.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards do you think that SO questions in the hot list are "immune" (to _lemmings_ coming from SO itself)? last time I checked, it wasn't so

Comment: Fair point @gnat; and you're right this means a couple of questions a week get "ruined". But I still don't believe that this causes the problems jmac's describing in that question.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards But those 6.7 million visits are spread out over many millions of questions, leaving the views *per question* (over the span of a day or so) reasonably low.  It's the concentration of so many views in such a short span of time *on a single question* that causes problems.

Comment: See my last comment @Servy. It impacts a few questions, yes. But it's highly unlikely it can impact the site; it's too big.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I would agree that it only really "ruins" a few questions, but how many really benefit?  (And by how much?)  If the feature as a whole has a net harmful effect, even if it's only a *little bit* harmful, it's still harmful.

Comment: The truth is the SO Guys think they are more important than the rest of the SE and that our problems over there are irrelevant and SE is wasting resources that could be better spent on SO.

Answer (score -32):

How well do you know Stack Overflow:

- How many questions are on SO?
- How many would you estimate have you read?
- How many questions has an experienced SO user read?
- How does this influence your moderation style?

Comment: Could you break this up into separate answers please? Lets folks vote on the ones they like.

Comment: @Shog9 none of those fits in my opinion. It's not meant as a quiz for the future moderators.

Comment: @Shog9, I would be happy to do so but seeing as it's the lowest-voted question of batch it doesn't seem worth the bother!

Comment: Heh, well, it wasn't that low when I left that first comment!

Comment: The trivia test is pointless, but I don't think the tail end is a bad question...as it gets to *"how much are you biased by statistics in your handling of moderation issues; where are your bias points, if they exist?"*.  Kind of makes me wonder if there's a place for moderators who have less information; like they have to make calls on issues without being able to see the names, avatars, previous questions, or rep scores...

Comment: The thing that interest me (and only me, apparently!!) is how little any single person can "know" the site. For example, if you've read 60,000 questions (which seems like an impressive amount of reading), you've only read less than 1% of the questions on the site. I'm interested in how this affects someone's approach to moderation. I would be very attracted to a moderator who acknowledged this interesting issue and explained how it affects that moderator's approach to the job.