# Provide a summary of review activities in candidates stats

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, election, nominations

Per my experience as a flagger, reviewing (various flags) is a substantial part of moderator duties, therefore I would like to have a better understanding of how active / experienced candidate is in this regard.

I would appreciate if [candidates stats page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/#stackoverflow) would let me see:

1. Total amount of reviews performed
2. Total amount of review badges earned
3. Number of review [suspensions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-suspension/info) (0 if none)
4. Review [audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-audits/info) summary: pass/fail rate and rate of total reviews/failed audits

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [came up last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168992/february-2013-community-moderator-election#comment498397_168992) when we first rolled out the "review history" links on election posts:

> Given the emphasis on "review history" in this post I was expecting a new page with nice aggregate statistics, such as audit success/fail/rate, breakdowns by categories of reviews, number and % approval of suggested edits, % of "do nothing" or "acceptable" in relevant queues, skip rate, and so on.

To which I replied,

> I regularly look at quite a bit of aggregate information on reviewers... That's great for picking out certain problems. It's also incredibly misleading when you're comparing individuals: two people can have very similar stats (in terms of number of reviews, decisions made, even audit failures) and yet vastly different styles when it comes down to the actual decisions they make. If you want to know what someone's doing when moderating the site, there's no substitute for actually looking at that in detail.

If you're picking your candidates based on how good they are at quickly grinding through a large number of tasks, then totals are exactly what you want. But that's a stupid way to pick a candidate. Yes, moderators do need to process very large number of posts quickly... But they also need to be able to do so *accurately*: with binding votes, they don't have the luxury of lazily clicking whichever button is least likely to get them push-back.

And that's why the link just takes you to the candidate's review history page. You do get a total number, if that's what you're looking for - but you also get a chance to click through and see what the candidate *actually **did***. Are they...

- ...clicking "Looks Good" on terrible posts?
- ...closing reasonable posts?
- ...leaving open problematic posts?
- ...approving pointless edits?

**You be the judge!** If so, that big impressive number starts to look a bit sad.

This is your chance to review the actions of a potential moderator *based on the actual moderation that they've done* - so make the most of it!

Comment: that's... a pretty compelling reasoning. Consider tagging my request [meta-tag:status-declined] (I think you didn't yet make golden badge in this tag, that one would make a solid step towards it)

Comment: I...didn't even know that link was there. Huh.

Answer (score 3):

I could see how this data might be useful, but the only request that could potentially be fulfilled at the moment is counting the number of review badges earned (and I'm a bit hesitant to do that since there's no particularly good way to grab information for just those badges).

Everything else would require the API to expose information that it currently doesn't. You can request that the API be updated to include this information [over on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/ask?tags=feature-request), at which point I could reconsider.

Comment: I don't follow. Why does it need a separate request? If the API needs to be extended isn't that an internal architectural decision nothing to do with us end users?

Comment: thanks! am I right to assume that API doesn't allow to retrieve number that is (publicly) shown at candidate profile -> activity -> reviews sub-tab ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/users/529758/h2co3?tab=activity&sort=reviews))?

Comment: @MartinSmith I (along with [Yi Jiang](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang)) maintain the election statistics page, but we are not Stack Exchange employees and only have access to what Stack Exchange provides publicly. So, if the data isn't available, someone has to request that it is before it's there for me to pull.

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't realise that was separate and not maintained by SE employees. Sorry!

Comment: @gnat Yep, that's right. I don't think there's necessarily any reason the information isn't available (except maybe the suspension count), it's just that there hasn't been a compelling need for it to have been added yet.

Comment: @MartinSmith Not a problem. It's obviously *hosted* by SE, but I do get blamed when things break. :P

Comment: I see, thanks. I guess then I [will ask candidates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220319/165773 "in this question") to provide this manually (except for audits stuff, which is too cumbersome to find out) and will take care on pushing for automated stats gathering to next elections

Comment: ...to next elections in whatever SE site these will be, not necessarily SO (eg, [Workplace](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2333/168) will likely have elections soon enough)