# Refreshing answer list during initial load causes crash

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

It's possible to pull the answer list down and trigger a refresh before the initial load completes if the answers load slowly enough, which crashes the app when at least one of the loads completes.

The expected behaviour would probably be that you aren't allowed to pull to refresh until that initial load finishes.

Comment: Or just that nothing would happen when you fire a pull to refresh as it is still loading.

Comment: @TimStone do you by chance recall which question you were looking at when the crash happened? Also, (to aid debugging) which device are you using?

Comment: @ArieLitovsky Yep, I was viewing [Provide a summary of review activities in candidates stats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220522), which I got to from a reputation increase notification in the feed (I was actually trying to reproduce [the app putting Shog's gravatar by my name](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AaJja.png), but that happened once and hasn't happened again since). I'm using an iPhone 4. iOS 7.0.4.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped me match it with a crashalytics report ;)

Comment: @ArieLitovsky That's what I get for writing bug reports at midnight while only half-awake; leaving out the important bits! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking through the crash logs, I found the one matching the question mentioned in the comments above. It seems that the crash would occur when a user **consistently tries to reload the question while it's loading** (as you correctly assume), though only when the app tries to scroll down and focus on a particular answer/comment.

However, even when that logic was patched up to prevent the crash, this type of user behavior was breaking the desired functionality (automatically scrolling down to an answer). In order to prevent this, I disallow user scrolling until such a flow is complete, though only in these very particular scenarios (where we are a target comment/answer to focus on).

**This issue should be fixed in the next build - version 0.1.15**

Comment: Those pesky users! Thanks for the quick fix! :)