# Are "hot questions" being moderated too heavily?

Tags: discussion, moderation, hot-questions

In fact, in addition to moderation, do we have a problem with people editing these questions?

This question is largely provoked by two questions I've seen on StackOverflow:

[Is a Java string really immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945049/is-a-java-string-really-immutable)

[What is this operator <=> in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927117/what-is-this-operator-in-mysql)

In the first question, there were some good and useful edits to the question, but then we also had people making edits which completely changed the gist of the question and made some of the top-rated answers seem half-irrelevant (and I recall, at one point, comments on those answers to that effect).

The second question used to contain a number of comments questioning its suitability as a question, and encouraging it to be downvoted or closed. I think there were good points there (somewhat biased because my own comment was in there) that the question did not show the minimal bar of effort required; a quick Google search has the answer in the top two results. In addition to that, the question is readily identified as a duplicate. But somebody has deleted all of the comments on the question at least twice, and now to anybody who can't view how the votes are split, it looks like this question is a shining example of what we want to see on StackOverflow.

Do we have a problem with too-heavy moderation on hot questions? Are users too eager to edit these questions to "improve" them, even at the cost of completely changing their core focus? And if so, what can we do to prevent these problems?

Answer (score 9):

> Do we have a problem with too-heavy moderation on hot questions?

The Workplace has had to deal with the repercussions of the "hot questions" list for a long time. I generally will proactively protect any question that hits that list and has 2 or more "on way to deletion" answers on it. Which turns out to be most of them.

> And if so, what can we do to prevent these problems?

You need to vote to close questions which aren't clear. This is how you fight this problem. Questions which are vague or nebulous or poorly written and hit that list are the problems.  If a question isn't clear, don't just up/downvote it - vote to close it. Closed questions are not on the "hot questions" list.

We frequently do this too, closing a question which is "popular" but bad by Stack Exchange standards, to edit and let it "cool off."

Just be thankful you don't have questions which anyone and their mother can post an "answer" to.

Comment: _Just be thankful you don't have questions which anyone and their mother can post an "answer" to_ -- wish I could upvote this twice. SO guys just don't value how lucky they are to have concrete implementation questions; once hot list hits more subjective sites like [Workplace or Programmers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221163/165773), brainless _meh_ answers from passers by turn into nightmare

Comment: Voting to close is only half the answer, I think. The first question I gave as an example was a perfectly good question by itself with no reason to be closed; but people still edited it to change its intended meaning.

Answer (score 3):

This is an obvious consequence of allowing every single user to moderate [almost] every single question.  When a question is being viewed by a very large number of users at the same time, it ends up with a lot more moderation actions on it than it normally would.  Unless you remove the ability for every single user to moderate posts, the problem isn't really solvable.

There is a possibility for a moderator to lock posts, but that's *generally* not something that would be beneficial here.  It can be a last resort if things start getting entirely out of control, but it has the side effect of preventing beneficial voting, answers, edits, etc.  in addition to the potentially harmful ones.

Comment: Maybe it would be beneficial to have multi-level protects. Like you could have a 10-rep protect, but also a almost-frozen 1k protect.

Comment: @bjb568 Protecting is entirely different from locking.  I'm not talking about protecting at all in this answer.  You're talking about issues with closing/reopening/editing.  None of that is affected by a question being protected.

Comment: 1) Maybe I don't understand this, but wasn't protect the effect of people hating freeze? I don't have the link but it was "freezing isn't good" "low-rep users cause noise in hot questions" and "Ok, now there is a protect feature that makes it so that you don't have to freeze it". Now protect is weak. 2) I'm talking about all kinds of noise related to popularity. The threshold stays the same for stuff, while the popularity goes up driving noise. Closing/reopening/editing maybe should be affected somehow by protects too.

Comment: @bjb568 Protecting a question is designed to solve an entirely different question than the one you are describing.  It should not be changed; it serves it's intended purpose just fine.  The fact that it isn't designed to solve this problem is exactly why I didn't bring it up in my answer.

Comment: Change the design. Make multiple variables when protecting such as rep to (edit|flag|vote|comment). If you want to give it a new name besides "protect" because it's not the "intended purpose", that's fine.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem "isn't really solvable". For example, hot questions could require edit reviews for users with less than 5k rep, rather than the usual 2k bar. I'm interested in hearing other solutions, and whether people think this is actually a problem or if I'm alone in this.

Comment: @bjb568 At that point it's an entirely different feature with an entirely different purpose.  It's not really related to protecting at that point.

Comment: @ChrisHayes That's a pretty radical change that would take a considerable amount of effort to implement, would greatly complicate the documentation of the site, it's ease of use, and it also doesn't address closures either.  And all of this for a *very* small percentage of questions.

Comment: @Servy That's why it's only an example solution and not a feature request. :)

Comment: ["It's the concentration of so many views in such a short span of time on a _single question_ that causes problems."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220314/2014-so-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/220325#comment714217_220325)

Comment: @gnat What point are you trying to make with that quote?

Comment: that in regular questions, that aren't exposed that heavily, this is not a problem. Heavy editing of the hot questions is a [known issue](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/5413/31260) "it takes some time to figure how to clean up ambiguous wording while preserving the essence of original. In regular questions this works like a charm, but when editing a hot one, I often find out that when I'm done with edit, someone already posted an answer that invalidates my edit. And answer that exploits another minor ambiguity. And yet another, and so on, until my brain explodes..."