# Ethics of reviews against one's own posts

Tags: discussion, review

I was given an ethical quandary the other day regarding a review.  I wonder if the SE network can or should put in a filter to prevent something like this happening.  I believe the circumstances can apply to any SE site.

The sequence of events was:

1. I posted an answer to a question.  It contained three paragraphs which
   gave the answer and some justification and references.
2. Someone gave my answer an upvote (not an acceptance).
3. Another user posted an answer which was a one-liner which
       repeated the core of my answer but not any of the justification.  I
       did not immediately notice this.
4. I noticed the Very Low Quality review queue contained an entry and I started
       to review it.  It was the other user's one line answer.

This is my quandary.  Should I:

- Recommend deletion.  Be thought of as rejecting a competing
  answer to my own in spite.
- Edit the post to improve it.  This would make it more like my own
  earlier post and would look as though I'd tried to answer twice.
- Click 'Looks good' and let it through - although it was low
  quality.

After mulling the options, I clicked '*skip*' to wimp out and let someone else make the decision.

Is it possible and/or desirable for there to be a filter such that VLQ reviews are not offered to people who already have a post on the question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't just click the *[Looks OK](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232342/165773)* button if the answer isn't good.

To a large degree it doesn't matter that you've already tendered an answer, we trust you to be honest in your appraisal. If you feel you cannot be impartial then use the *Skip* button.

If you think you're up to it and can be impartial then your only option is to recommend deletion as you are obviously not in a position to edit it into shape (you would be better off editing your own answer into an even better one).

Answer (score 6):

Cast your vote. Unless you're a mod, you're vote isn't the end all be all. If you vote for deletion based on low quality, others will have to confirm. You could downvote and provide a reason as well. If you're *really* afraid of us reading you're mind, you could (although I don't really recommend) doing a drive-by downvote, but providing a reason is kosher and recommended.

I once recall a question on ServerFault where there was much speculation, in part because *no one* could find explicit recommendations from MS on the matter. Everyone *knew* the 'right' answer, but no one could 'prove' it. Therefore, someone d/v'd my answer, because I didn't produce citation, after someone else did (sound familiar?) However, they left a comment saying *why* they downvoted. So, I went, researched on my *own*, and find citation that ended up being *different* from the other answer. After the edit, they reversed their vote.

So, while it's likely they could have just pinched your answer, there's little you can do to prove/remedy that, it's just a flaw of the system, however a downvote and comment will show where you stand on low quality answers.