# Change wording of "Looks OK" on Low Quality Post review option

Tags: feature-request, review, wording

The "Looks OK" option on Low Quality Post reviews is not ideally worded.

Due to the fact the post has been reported for Low Quality means *in most cases* "something" is wrong with it. Even if deletion or editing is not the solution, it shouldn't be concluded as "Looks OK".

### Propose

Change "Looks OK" to something which more accurately represents the outcome being used for the review.

Such as:
"Deletion Not Required"
"Don't Delete"

Then our choice is what the review outcome actually is - "I don't think this should be deleted" rather than "this looks ok to me".

If people have to choose "Looks OK" for what is a *terrible* post but doesn't need deleting, they might be forced towards a general "meh" attitude "Doesn't look OK but whatever".
Whereas, their choosing "Don't Delete" might push "No, this does not need deleting, but I'm going to damn well downvote and/or comment after this review" *

<sub><sup>* I'm no psychologist and this is likely total cobblers, but sounds feasible to me</sup></sub>

---

*Suggested Edits* don't have "Looks OK", they have "Approve", and the Low Quality review choices should be allowed the same logic and sanity :)

Comment: If you say *If people have to choose "Looks OK" for what is a terrible post but doesn't need deleting, they might be forced towards a general "meh" attitude "Doesn't look OK but whatever"* why isn't **Meh** one of your alternatives for *Looks OK*?

Comment: @rene "Meh" is a result of choosing "Looks OK", I want to resolve that, not implement it :P

Comment: I've seen plenty of questions get "Looks OK" from triage, despite the fact that those posts didn't seem to believe in sentences. I'd rather not "Meh" -> "Looks OK". "Meh" probably needs someone to edit.

Comment: Definitely! That is so long overdue. I can't tell how often I just always clicked "Skip" until I realized that "Looks Ok" doesn't actually mean that the post looks Ok.

Comment: related: [Rename “Looks Good” or add a “Looks OK, just Incorrect” in Low Quality Question Review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232342/165773)

Comment: Also related: [Improve help text for the low-quality-posts queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220794/255554). The only thing that keeps me from calling it a duplicate of [Rename “Looks Good” or add a “Looks OK, just Incorrect” in Low Quality Question Review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143015/255554) is its [tag:status-completed] – I could just copy my answer here.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft It's not a dupe because that was a change which I disagree with and suggest something different here :)

Comment: Similar suggestion on SO https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278518/change-text-of-looks-ok-button-in-low-quality-queue/423153#423153

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your suggested rephrasing "Deletion Not Required" or "Don't Delete" is that it implies the options for moderators are limited to "Delete" or "Let it be".  A conscientious mod could opt to improve the post instead.

I suggest a more accurate rephrasing that matches the mod's decision not to take any action:

> No Action Required

Which should cover all possible reasons for why a mod would want to leave a post alone.

Comment: Actually, this might clarify the purpose of the Edit button, which at present is often misunderstood. It really means "Don't delete this — *I can fix it*", **not** "I'd like to make some random changes to this post".