# Clarify meaning of “Looks OK” in the Low Quality Answers queue

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

In the Low Quality Answers queue “Looks OK” option has a description

> It is an honest attempt at answering the question and is not low
> quality.

In most of cases when a reviewer wants to click “Looks OK” option, they agree with the first part “ It is an honest attempt at answering the question”.
However the answer still may be of low quality, but has some value and doesn’t need to be deleted.

I suggest to **remove “and is not low quality”** to avoid any confusion.

Alternatively it can be changed to **“ and the provided information may be useful”.**

Suggestion from Cody Gray‘s comment: It should say "**No action necessary**".

According to [Guidelines for reviewing Low quality answers][1] “Looks OK. This is the correct choice for answers that aren't eligible for deletion, or for questions that aren't closeable.” So alternatively the text can be changed to

> This is an honest attempt at answering the question **and isn't eligible
> for deletion**.

Please also see [Change wording of "Looks OK" on Low Quality Post review option](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258249/change-wording-of-looks-ok-on-low-quality-post-review-option), that has the same concern, but suggests to change the button text rather than clarification description.

The button used to be "Looks Good", but it was changed to “Looks OK” in  [Rename "Looks Good" or add a "Looks OK, just Incorrect" in Low Quality Question Review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143015/377214) . However clarification text was not changed at that time and became inconsistent with the button label.

Comment: It depends. Answers of very low quality are not answers at all and not worth keeping around. We got to draw the line somewhere, so a remark about quality is not out of place there. Maybe the phrasing can be improved, but I wouldn't drop it entirely.

Comment: @Mast for “not answers at all and not worth keeping around” there is a different button “Delete”. I am talking about button “Looks OK”

Comment: It should say "No action necessary".

Comment: Related, "prior art" on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278518/change-text-of-looks-ok-button-in-low-quality-queue; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401245/can-we-find-a-better-wording-for-looks-ok-in-the-review-queues; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318203/change-the-looks-ok-text-in-the-lqp-queue (tangential: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266428/low-quality-review-queue-meaning-of-looks-ok; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416713/when-choosing-looks-ok-in-the-first-answers-review-queue-the-wording-implie)

Comment: @CodyGray art priot to your prior art: [Low quality review records say "Looks Good" instead of "Looks OK"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234986/165773) and [Rename "Looks Good" or add a "Looks OK, just Incorrect" in Low Quality Question Review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143015/165773) :)

Comment: These may be helpful links to add to the information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-low-quality and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/282094 - they clairify the criteria for review, and mention that wrong answers that address the question shouldn't be deleted; downvoted instead.

Comment: A while back, it used to be "Looks Good", but it was changed due to [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143015/377214). The answer there says they considered other phrasings but ultimately decided with "Looks OK". I'd read that and incorporate some arguments from there.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, the button has been renamed , but clarification text was not changed at that time