# It still "Looks Good" in Network Profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts, network-profile

The review option in the Very Low Quality review queue [has been changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143015/357396) to "Looks OK" from "Looks Good" a few years ago. If we select "Looks OK" in the review queue, it still shows "Looks Good" in the network profile:

[image: Activity in network profile]

The change has already been applied in the per-site user activity; there it is shown as "Looks OK".

[image: Activity in user activity profile]

Can this be changed to "Looks OK" in the network profile too, for bringing uniformity?

Answer (score 4):

At some point in time (but I have no idea when) this has been fixed:

[image]

Comment: Should be [status-completed] or do we need a confirmation from a dev?

Comment: @41686d6564 yes, I've been informed that we can do so in clear cut cases. Most of the times we do leave that to staff.

Comment: Poke a dev with blunt stick until they dig in the code to see when it was done. ;)

Comment: I prefer you give them coffee, so they can do some actual work @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2