# notify users the comment is from the new review

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

There have been times when the target of a review where the comment appears has complained. (and this has been commented on [before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144527/what-should-i-do-when-a-user-complains-about-a-canned-review-comment-and-refuses).

(my example:)

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
>
> ...and this answer is two years old, and there are other answers to the question.

could there be some indication that the comment comes from this new review system? I do flag the comments as unconstructive, but it's this sort of response that makes me not want to actually review (or leave feedback as to why I am recommending deletion)

Comment: Excellent idea, I've had a couple of users question the comments it left on older posts as it wasn't clear why i was commenting on a years old post that was heretofore unquestioned.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144639/include-links-to-relevant-meta-posts-in-review-automatic-comments

Comment: I feel like I've seen this request before... can't find it though.