# Reviewing low quality posts leaving comment on your behalf

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

This might just be me, but When going through the low-quality post review, if you click recommend deletion, you get the **Add a comment for the author** dialog

[image]

Now I know that It says "Add a comment"  at the top, but what I, as a user, was presented with, was a list of reasons to recommend deletion(like it would be if you voted to close a question)

I didn't know that I was going to leave a canned response on the post, nor did some of the posters know that the response which I've left came from this interface.

I understand that it's a difficult problem to make it both clear, and still have the canned responses in the dialog.

maybe make it clearer that you're leaving a comment if you had a text box next to "Add a comment for the author" for a custom comment of some sort, or maybe if you did away with the titles of the canned comments, and just had the radio button next to the comments themselves, it might be more clear that you're leaving a comment.

What I think is probably the best long-term solution though, is to model the low-quality answer review like the close question review, where instead of leaving a canned comment that might confuse the asker, have some votes for deletion area for answers that reflects the votes to close area.  for questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [notify users the comment is from the new review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144624/notify-users-the-comment-is-from-the-new-review)

Comment: You might be surprised to learn that close voting will also leave a comment on your behalf if you select the duplicate option...

Answer (score 6):

I cannot stress enough the importance of reading what is on the screen when reviewing.

So I won't bother. But trust me, it's important. And the dialog makes it pretty clear what you're doing, IMHO.

The *reason* for attributing the comment to you and not tacking it on as an annotation or something is that... Well, you're the one saying why it should be deleted. If you're wrong, or someone has questions on what they can do to forestall the deletion, they can respond to you. If you don't like that, either don't leave a comment (it's the default option...) or don't delete stuff.

Comment: *resisting the temptation to make your first sentence 5x bigger and in red.

Comment: Actually, that's a good point. Have you perhaps considered introducing *more* features that will unpleasantly surprise people who don't read what's on the screen when reviewing?

Comment: A comment reply that I make all-to frequently is: "That is explained in the first paragraph/sentence/first half of the first sentence.". We need "the Duck" to appear fullscreen and actually peck these people, unfortunately technology lags behind need.

Answer (score 5):

The title of the dialog, along with the subtext, seems pretty clear to me.  If you didn't read it when reviewing the posts you may be surprised with what happens.  That's... inevitable.

As for choosing to not leave comments, it's not helpful for the poster to just have their content deleted.  The comments help them understand what they did wrong so they can fix it.  That's important.  Without it they'll just continue doing the same things over and over again.  There also tends to be a high percentage of newer users, or posts from when users were new, in this queue.  Many of them merely need to be told what the proper SO guidelines are, which is really one of the primary reasons the queue exists.

Comment: Thus: the modeling it after close question votes..  Right now, there is nothing indicating the that the comment is coupled with a deletion vote.

Comment: @SamIam Why should there be?  People can post such comments without voting to delete; it should affect how the comment is treated by the OP.