# List of low quality post "recommend deletion" comments

Tags: support, comments, review, low-quality-posts

I'm looking for the list of comment templates which are offered by the system when recommending deletion of a low-quality answer, so that I can reuse one of them in a related situation. Can I see this list somewhere, even when there aren't currently any low-quality posts in the queue?

Or is there a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answer which has a copy of the comment templates?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a list of Markdown code for the comments. All you have to do is copy-paste (triple-click on a code block to select all of it):

- **This is commentary on another post, not an answer**

  ```
  This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.
  ```

  Version for answers by low-reputation users:

  ```
  This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/349538).
  ```
- **This is a “thank you” comment**

  ```
  Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.
  ```

  Version for answers by low-reputation users:

  ```
  Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.
  ```

  Version for answers posted by the user who asked the question:

  ```
  Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, [**accept the answer**](/help/accepted-answer) that you found most helpful.
  ```
- **This is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment**

  ```
  This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/349538). You can also [add a bounty](/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.
  ```

  Version for answers by low-reputation users:

  ```
  This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/349538). Once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.
  ```
- **This is a different question posted as an answer**

  ```
  If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.
  ```
- **This is a link-only answer (and not spam)**

  ```
  While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
  ```

The following comment is only available in the [*Low quality posts* / *Low quality answers* review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing/180029#180029) when reviewing an answer posted by the user who asked the question:

- **This answer should be an edit to the question**

  ```
  Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.
  ```

Answer (score 2):

As a start, I found the following screenshot in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155564/191131):

[image: screenshot of the low-quality recommended deletion comments]