# Relative links in comments are broken on the network profile

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks, low-quality-posts, network-profile

When reviewing a Low Quality Post as Recommend Deletion and leaving an [automatic comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290699/349538), a From Review link appears to the review item. These comments are like any comments visible in the [Activity tab of the network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity).

The problem is that when clicking on the From Review link from the network profile, Stack Exchange's 404 page shows up. This is because the link  points to a relative link, `/review/low-quality-posts/12345678` instead of the absolute URL `http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12345678`, so stackexchange.com interprets it as `https://stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/12345678`, which doesn't exist.

This issue isn't very important since it's probably fairly rare that someone clicks that link from the network profile, but it would still be good to get it fixed.