# How to undo/fix an accidentally wrong review?

Tags: support, review, undo

I misclicked when doing a review [(this one)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16646904), and that was a terrible goof. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Your review is not binding, others will cover for your mishap. Nothing needs to be done for the review. You could simply visit the post and then do whatever you feel is appropriate.

Comment: [I did the same thing a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15319351). When I realized my mistake, I downvoted and flagged the answer and added the comment from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290699/349538) that I would have selected if I would have clicked Recommend Deletion with a note explaining my mistake (I just made another mistake and accidentally deleted that comment, I didn't know it was possible).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. This is (part of the reason) why a review requires multiple users to look at (except for First Posts / Late Answers, but mistakes there are easy to repair). Those other users will hopefully choose the right action, which will diminish the effects of your mistake. Also, you can always go back to the post and do what's necessary (vote and/or flag).