# Unclear on responses to certain reviews

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, low-quality-posts

I recently got to 2K  on SO. So, I can access the review queue of **low quality posts**.
I did quite some research & went through several meta questions to handle low quality posts as well as suggested edits. But, I still can't figure out how to tackle the following reviews. I am having issues deciding on the review response. I don't know if this the proper way to go about it, but can you give me a clear view on the following 3 reviews so that I get a clear understanding?

**Review 1** (low quality post)

[Android Photo Album App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083473/android-photo-album-app)

The OP asks

> Anybody has similar idea or code, please respond.

without actually describing his approach or providing with any efforts from his side. Also, **please respond** seems quite wrong for SO. So, am I correct in outright rejection of the post as **low quality**? Or should I just approve & then maybe, flag for being **too broad** or **unclear what you are asking**?

**Review 2** (suggested edit)

[just fixed a typo](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18087659/revisions)

The editor fixed a typo, but it was in the rendered output. Also, probably to make up for the minimum 6 chars, he made some minor required edits.

**Review 3** (low quality post)

[Append multiple items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621498/append-multiple-items/22083621#22083621)

This answer, is **wrong**. (Notice the skip in index numbers) So, does this make it *low quality*? Why so? I mean, it being *wrong* does not constitute it as a *low quality*, or does it?

Comment: About 3: Don't judge the rightness of the answer. That is reserved for votes.

Comment: Yeah, I am mostly getting confused with the domain of the mod task.

Comment: There are a few guides on meta, see this for example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141851/reviewing-low-quality-posts-when-to-delete

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I've been a diamond mod for almost a year, and was an active user of the moderation tools all along, and I still have plenty of times I'm not 100% on how/what to do. You have the right attitude here.

Comment: @sashkello I have seen that, maybe I need to re-read it a couple of times. Thanks for the reassurance Andrew.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil So, there is answer which states: "Note that wrong answers should not be deleted: deletion is for answers that “aren't even wrong”." and "Note that if a question is inappropriate for the site (off-topic, too broad, etc.), the right tool for the job is to vote to close" which should answer your points 3 and 1 respectively.

Comment: @sashkello I would be grateful if you convert your comments to an answer, they do actually *answer* my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this useful thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141851/reviewing-low-quality-posts-when-to-delete):

*1*. Question is answerable, but too broad or unclear, so:

> Note that if a question is inappropriate for the site (off-topic, too
>   broad, etc.), the right tool for the job is to vote to close (flag to
>   close if you don't have enough reputation). If you can understand what
>   is asked, the question “looks good”, even if it can't be answered
>   within the context of the site.

*3*. Answer is wrong, so should be downvoted, but:

> Note that wrong answers should not be deleted: deletion is for answers
>   that “aren't even wrong”.

And the edit:

*2*. Actually, this one is debatable. It is quite minor but does slightly improve the answer format. I'd say it's your call, I would approve it.

Comment: Ah, the **vote to close** and the **low quality posts** are 2 different flags & I should not **reject** because I should actually **vote to close**?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil That's right. Closing is for posts which can be potentially salvaged (i.e., edited by the OP into something answerable). Deletion is for posts for which there is no way to end up answerable.

Comment: Thanks! So, my basic confusion was that I did not quite get the difference in the *type of flag*.