# "Looks Good" for answers in low quality posts review queue is confusing

Tags: bug, review, low-quality-posts

From [the guidelines on reviewing low quality posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141857/162730) I've taken this advice:

> You should accept a post (Looks good)
>   ...
>   • [ANS] Note that answers that are clear and address the question at least a little, but are fundamentally wrong, should be downvoted, not deleted. A wrong answer still “looks good”.

Makes sense to me, but "Looks Good" is misleadingly worded. I suspect many people, especially those that haven't read mentioned guidelines, will be confused and may refrain from picking that option (perhaps choosing one of the "delete" options).

**Question: can we do something about this?**

Perhaps rewording "Looks Good" to something else (suggestions welcome), or the option to downvote an answer and have an "I'm done" button?

Comment: Is this somewhat similar: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143015/rename-looks-good-or-add-a-looks-ok-just-incorrect-in-low-quality-question