# Can't find an answer containing a lot of predefined comments for first-post/late-answer reviews

Tags: discussion, review, search

A while ago I saw a very nice answer left on a question about reviewing or some such thing. The answer had perhaps eight or ten fairly generally applicable scripted-out comments to leave on posts of various poor qualities, so I figured I'd keep it around for later use.

Unfortunately, I no longer have it open in tabs; sifting through browser history doesn't make it pop up; Bing, Google, and site search are frustratingly incapable of interpreting my very vague memory (comment? review? flag?) of just exactly what keywords were used... so here we are. I do know it was on either M.SE or M.SO, but of course that is not all that helpful.

Anybody know of such an answer offhand? I doubt there can be more than one, or at most two, barring the description of AutoReviewComments perhaps, which I already use. ([This answer in "Reviewing low quality posts: when to delete"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195885/274165) isn't it either.)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments maybe?

Comment: @Shog9: Huh, I'm pretty sure I'd never seen that before. Useful, but rather more specific than I'd been thinking of. Will keep it around though I think.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing

Comment: @gnat: There are no scripted comments in there, although the format is certainly rather similar.