# Add link to Recommend deletion guidelines directly in the Low Quality Queue

Tags: feature-request, review, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts

All the guidance the Low Quality queue offers is this, for deleting answers:

> Recommend Deletion to recommend that this answer be deleted

That's not guidance at all! After much searching, I finally managed to turn up this post:

[Reviewing low quality posts: when to delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141851/reviewing-low-quality-posts-when-to-delete)

Which is really great and helpful. However, it shouldn't be so hard to find! I think it should be linked *directly within the review queue*. I am aware that clicking on the "Recommend Deletion" button pulls up a number of reasons with explanations, but I think having a link to a guide in the (more) dropdown would be helpful as well.

**Could a link to the above question, or a similar question with similar answers, be added to the help dropdown in the Low Quality Queue?**

Comment: **Please Note** - the question referenced here is a duplicate, which has a broken link to the reviewing instructions. I flagged it for moderator attention. In my answer, I referred to a section of the previous related question, [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing)

Answer (score 4):

I completely agree! Reviewing is a privilege, and the best way to contribute responsibly to the community is to do it correctly. As you said, it took you a long time to find a post with thorough instructions, and even then, it's a duplicate. Also, as you can see from my comment, it has a link to a page which no longer exists.

A link in the help dropdown is an excellent idea, and I think a good choice would be [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/272239),  which is a part of a description of all the review queues. That way, we can learn about the other review tasks at the same time if we want!

(It may even be useful to replicate this request for each of the queues, and link to the relevant answers in that question!)