# Moderator actions while reviewing the Low Quality queue

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools, low-quality-posts

I have read the [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/278094) and [Reviewing low quality posts: when to delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141851/278094) and I understand when each action should be taken. Yet those do not address moderator only actions that can be taken from within the review queue.

There are lots of cases when reviewing the low quality queue I convert the answer to a comment (that is a mod only action). That unfortunately does not count towards my review history, all it does is remove it from the review queue.

Is it possible to also make any moderator action count as reviewing that specific post?