# As a moderator, how should I treat flags concerning my own activity?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, moderators

So here's an example, a user disliked my comment.
[image]

Honestly I'd rather ignore this flag though marking it helpful, but I don't want to discuss here what it the best action in this particular case in general. All I wonder about is what should I do as a moderator. I mean:

- Act just like I am acting usual, but this is strange because even the most honest judge in the world does not adjudicate himself.
- Ignore this flag to avoid the possibility of preconceived decision.

Comment: How is this a feature request?

Comment: @Catija this is a feature request - "What if we'll just won't allow to moderate flags on a particular moderator to this moderator him/herself and just pass it to the others?"

Comment: That's not reflected in your question title and it's not even mentioned until the last sentence of the body of the question and looks like an afterthought. It would make this significantly different that the dupe but would need to be made more prominent. Though, even if reworded, the answers to the other question don't make it look  like something SE is interested in implementing. Regardless, you're asking two questions here - "What should I do?" and "Can we add a feature that prevents mods from responding to flags about themselves?"... which makes this pretty difficult to answer.

Comment: @Catija I believe that those two are quite related and it's ok to have this as as single question.

Comment: shabunc, Few people are going to read to the bottom of a post and notice a passing reference to a feature request to vote on as such.  If would like to suggest a remedy in earnest, I would suggest posting a specific feature request and make what you are actually proposing more prominent in the content. That's the only way to gauge interest and to flesh out any concerns or gotchas to what you are proposing specifically.

Comment: @RobertCartaino ok, sounds good, will create a separate question and will edit this one.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155425/moderators-should-not-be-allowed-to-moderate-questions-they-have-participated-in/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You let another moderator handle it.

I see there are only two of you -- if your fellow moderator won't/can't handle the flag, I'd recommend you bring it to the super-secret mod room and ask a community manager to handle it. If your fellow moderator won't/can't handle it, and you don't want to/can't ask a community manager, then review your decision with a moderator from another site before you do anything.